# Replace constructor with a factory/or a builder

Tags: java, design-patterns, intellij-idea

I am using IntelliJ 10 Comnunity Edition, and I noticed there are two refactoring options which are similar:

-Replace constructor with factory
-Replace constructor with builder

What are the differences between these two? When would I want to use over another?

Thanks

Comment: Are you asking about the difference between the builder pattern and the factory pattern?  They are similar patterns in that they abstract-out object creation, but they are not identical, hence the discrete commands in Idea.  In any case, I'd suggest comparing the two in Wikipedia.

Comment: Whoa, you're kidding me? IntelliJ has this built in? I'm downloading trial!

Comment: IntelliJ has A LOT of refactoring options, some of which I've never heard before, kind of makes sense as the parent company Jetbrains makes a dedicated refactoring tool (Resharper).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use constructors to build an object when it can satisfy all the invariants. To understand the difference between builder and factory look this post [What is the difference between Builder Design pattern and Factory Design pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/757743/what-is-the-difference-between-builder-design-pattern-and-factory-design-pattern)