# Is there a pattern where you have a class whose job it is to instantiate common implementations of another class?

Tags: c#, oop, design-patterns, helper

I want to call it a "Helper" but this seems way too general.

Let's say I have a class called `WidgetCranker` and `WidgetCranker` can be set up to crank out widgets of the type `Square`, `Keyhole` and `GearShape`. I can also specify which `Color` I want my widgets to be and which `Label` I want stamped on them.

Now, setting up each individual instance of `WidgetCranker` is fairly involved, the constructor just gives you an empty `WidgetCranker` and you have to manually set the type and colour of widgets you want to crank.

```
WidgetCranker keyholeWidget = new WidgetCranker();
keyholeWidget.Type = WidgetTypes.Keyhole;
keyholeWidget.Color = WidgetColors.Red;
keyholeWidget.Label = "ACME Industries Prototype 1";
```

But I have a class that requires a lot of `WidgetCranker`s that pretty much all look the same except for the label. I want to make my code more readable and less laborious to maintain, so I create a helper class that does all the lifting for me. So the above now becomes:

```
WidgetCranker keyholeWidget = WidgetCrankerHelper.RedKeyhole("ACME Industries Prototype 1");
```

My question is twofold:

1. Is this an actual design pattern and if so, what do we call it? I want to call it a factory, but it most definitely **isn't** a factory pattern. We're creating exactly the same kind of object in every case, just instantiating them differently. I **know** it's a type of "Helper", but I want to be more specific than that if I can. It's a helper that does a very specific thing.
2. Given that "Helper" is a very generic name, I feel that just naming the method by what it produces isn't enough. I should name it so that it's obvious what it does. So would `MakeRedKeyhole` be better or `BuildRedKeyhole`? I don't want to use `GetRedKeyhole` because that implies we're getting back a reference to an existing instance and not creating a brand new one.

Comment: Its still  a factory.. just _not an abstract factory_.

Comment: definitely a factory :)

Comment: There you go. Thanks guys. I was thinking of abstract factories and got myself in a pickle.

Comment: a factory can return different types of concrete objects.  However its still valid to return simply objects configured differently as opposed to different types.

Comment: This is the Factory Method pattern (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern - scroll down for C# sample code), and is commonly implemented as static methods on the class itself.

Comment: Cool, that was my other problem with calling it a factory. I wasn't sure that you could still call it a factory if all it was doing was configuration on one type of object (i.e. not different implementations of an interface, just plain simple configuration on a single class of object).

Comment: A [Builder][1] pattern should also be considered.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/757743/what-is-the-difference-between-builder-design-pattern-and-factory-design-pattern

Answer (score 0):

I tend to stay away from the term "Helper" as all classes are supposed to be helpful, right?  :)

I think that calling this either Factory or Builder would be acceptable. The point of abstract factory is to encapsulate the construction/instantiation of an object. It *could* return different types, but it doesn't *need* to. The type consuming the factory shouldn't care.

I tend to use the "Builder" name when it is doing any complex construction like this.