# Difference between Abstract factory and builder?

Tags: design-patterns, builder, abstract-factory

Sorry for asking again. I have searched over web but couldn't understand hence i have to put here. Here what I research by my self. I studied from head first design pattern.

**Abstract factory pattern :**

[image]

As per the differences i studied that builder some senses it is a Factory, but
it only creates one type, most of the time.
So can i say NYStore in above image is builder as it returns pizza object to client?
am i correct? Please give your answer on bases of above example which may help me to learn it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between Builder Design pattern and Factory Design pattern?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/757743/what-is-the-difference-between-builder-design-pattern-and-factory-design-pattern)

Comment: The distinction is often about *why* rather than *how*

Comment: @doctorlove So we can say NYStore is builder as it returns pizza object which composite of dough,sauces, vegges etc object isn't it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Interesting.  I'd recommend a few changes to the diagram to make it fit the classical Builder pattern as defined by the GoF.

The big difference is that in the builder pattern, the "director" gets to be unaware of the details of the builders.  So instead of having a class called `NyPizzaStore` with a method called `createPizza()` that (obviously) is highly tuned to creating a NY style pizza, you might instead have a class call `PizzaChef` that takes in an instance of a class that customizes how the details of how the pizza is made.  (For this example/analogy, let's rename rename`PizzaIngerdientFactory` to `Recipe` so we can treat it just a bit differently).  So that gives you `PizzaChef.createPizza(Recipe r)`.  The PizzaChef class does not need to worry if the clams are fresh or frozen, he simply calls each of the builders in turn and creates the desired pizza.  This is pivotal to the difference...there is only one PizzaChef and he is unaware of the details (subclasses) of the Recipe.

A nice side effect of this is that you can easily mix-and-match the builders that make up the Recipe class such that you can create a NewHavenStyle pizza by using all the same ingredient builders as the NYStyle, but swap in a `BrickFiredThinCrust` instead.  Much more customizable.  `Recipe` becomes a holder for the builder instances.

And of course, now I'm hungry :)

---

Be careful that you do not confuse the name of a pattern (which is a reusable technique involving, almost always, multiple objects / participants / roles), and the name of a specific role in a pattern.  Additionally, often patterns build on top of each other and have a lot of overlap.

In the Builder **pattern**, there is a `Director` object that would have a `createSomething()` method (not call it).  That method would call, in a very formulaic way, the one or more part builders.  The client has a reference to the `Director`, and passes in the builder(s).  The client, directly or indirectly, influence what gets built.  The Director has no need to be a subclass of anything, it could be a simple, sealed class.  `PizzaChef` is not the client but rather the director.  It does not inherit from anything, nor does it get inherited.  The client in this case might be something like a `Customer` class.

Now, just as the `Abstract Factory` pattern is built upon a set of `Factory Methods` (from the pattern of that name), you could have a `Builder` pattern utilize an `Abstract Factory` .  You could pass in the builders to the Director as an AbstractFactory.  In that case, the `Recipe` would be your AbstractFactory, and `NyStyleRecipe` would subclass `Recipe` and provide the builder methods that the `PizzaChef` class would use to create a pizza.  In this sepecific implementation, the `Directpr` of the `Builder` pattern would indeed be client as described in your original diagram.

But as I tried to allude to before, that is not the only have to implement the `Builder` pattern, and I think it adds limitations that Builder is designed to overcome.  I would use a composeable `Recipe` class instead because you can then mix-and-match ingredients much more easily.  There is not *really* a connection between thin crust and NY-style pizza.  New Haven style uses thin style too.

```
Recipe newyorkStyle = new Recipe(
   new ThinCrustBuilder(), 
   new RedSauceBuilder(), 
   new FreshClamsBuilder(), 
   new ElectricOvenBuilder());

Recipe newhavenStyle = new Recipe(
   new ThinCrustBuilder(), 
   new WhiteSauceBuilder(), 
   new FreshClamsBuilder(), 
   new BrickOvenBuilder());

PizzaChef chef = new PizzaChef ();

nyPizza = checf.createPizza(newyorkStyle);

nhPizza = checf.createPizza(newhavenStyle);
```

Note that I used composeable builders to reuse the thin crust and the fresh clams.  This would not be as easy with an `Abstract Factory`

I hope that clarifies the differences a bit more!

Comment: so what i understood is if in above example NYStore as client it is an abstract factory. but if some director try to invoke NYStore createpizza metthode to get single pizza object (which is made up of other ingredient object) then NYStore  is a builder. am i correct? i like your answer specially now i am hungry part :)

Comment: Edited to add more clarity, let me know if you have any other questions

Answer (score 3):

The Builder and Abstract Factory patterns are similar in that they both look at construction at an abstract level. However, the Builder pattern is concerned with how a
single object is made up by the different factories, whereas the Abstract Factory pattern
is concerned with what products are made. The Builder pattern abstracts the
algorithm for construction by including the concept of a director. The director is
responsible for itemizing the steps and calls on builders to fulfill them. Directors do
not have to conform to an interface.

Other example (than yours) may be creating products instead of the client
explicitly declaring fields of type ProductA and ProductB, say, the Product object the
builder returns is actually a list of parts, which can have different lengths and contents
depending on the director that was in charge at its creation.

Comment: So can I say NYStore is builder as it returns pizza object which composite of dough,sauces, vegges etc object?

Comment: Yes. But remember to build an object (in your example add dough, sauces etc.)  and not also return it. This is because there is this cloud pattern CQRS (if you are familiar with) which says that methods either change objects either return (read) them but not both.

Comment: By the way, if my answer helped you please don't hesitate to rate up or at least approve it. I would upload an image to be easier to understand but I don't have enough reputation :D

Comment: done. if possible can you  send me image with explain details mail on surendersinghpawar@gmail.com, i can upload with answer.

Answer (score 0):

*Builder* contains the knowledge necessary to build specific parts of a whole, calling on a factory to make the desired parts. *Abstract Factory* ensures that a consistent set of those parts is created. For example I may have a `FordBuilder` for assembling Ford vehicles and `GMBuilder` for GM vehicles. Now using the Builder pattern, a client can call the manufacture method on a director.

```
class Director
...
Vehicle manufacture(VehicleBuilder builder)
{
    builder.buildFrame();
    builder.buildDoors(2);
    builder.buildWheels(4);
    return builder.GetVehicle()
}
```

Note that while the director is giving the directions, its the builder that knows how those parts fit together to make a coherent whole. So `FordBuilder` knows how to build a Ford by assembling the frame by calling a method `makeFrame()` for the frame, `makeDoor()` for the doors and `makeWheel()` for the wheels on some factory class call it `ComponentFactory`. `GMBuilder` does the same for GMs. Now suppose we want to use the same builder to make either trucks or sedans because we see the steps for doing both are identical. However, the combination of frame, doors, and wheels has to be compatible, you can't mix sedan frames with truck wheels! This is where the *Abstract Factory* pattern come in. An abstract class or interface `AbstractComponentFactory` supports the 3 methods just mentioned. And now `FordSedanFactory` which subclasses `AbstractComponentFactory` implements `makeFrame()`, `makeDoor()` and `makeWheel()` and ensures that they all return compatible sedan frame, doors, and wheels. `FordTruckFactory` ensures the same for trucks. Now the specific builder `FordBuilder` or `GMBuilder` can execute the process or recipe for building a sedan or truck as requested by a customer, making calls on `makeFrame()`, `makeDoor()` and `makeWheel()` as needed, safe in the knowledge that that what comes off the line is a proper sedan or truck and not some non-functioning chimera.

Answer (score -1):

In pizza example, if NYstore act as client then it get productA, produtB... etc from factory and can directly access, but if we treat NYStore as pizzachef (as suggested by tcarvin ) and client accces it to get complete pizza, it act as builder (pizzache as directore and ingredient class as builder)
Following image can exact tell what is the exact difference
note : I am putting this image so whoever visit this post can understand easily.

NOW I AM HUNGRY also.

[image]

Thanks to liviu for this image.