# Which pattern is this? (Factory/Builder/Mapper/other)

Tags: php, design-patterns, factory, datamapper, builder

I took clues from `DataMapper` pattern to create something like this:

```php
class BusinessObjectCreator
{
    public function create()
    {
        //Acquire Data
        $number = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "number", FILTER_SANITIZE_INT);

        //create and populate object
        $object = new Object();
        $object->setNumber($number);
        return $object;
    }
}

//usage:
$objectInstance = (new BusinessObjectCreator())->create();

//examples of usage once created
$objectInstance->someBusinessFunction();
echo $objectInstance->getNumber();
```

But to me it also looks like a `Factory` pattern or a `Builder` pattern.

Which is it? and did I code it up correctly?

Purpose is to create an object instance *populated* with data.  Then I can use the created object to do operations on the data.

Comment: Just a casual comment/question: Why don't you use dependency injection? In other words, why don't you pass an Object to the create method?

Comment: Do you mean why don't I create the object elsewhere and then pass it into `create()` function, (then populate the object, and return it)?

Comment: ^ if I understood it correctly ... I can.  It will just make the pattern different.  I can create object elsewhere and change the name to `BusinessObjectPopulator` to reflect the purpose better.

Comment: Yes, I understand that this (pass the object as a parameter or create the object inside the function) is not what you're asking. I just wanted to point out something that can be improved. As for the question per se, this patters seems like a factory to me and it can still be improved by having your class to implement an interface.

Comment: what kind of an interface do you mean?  I am not sure I understood.  Also, I can further improve on this by injecting input source rather than having input source hardcoded into the class like I have right now.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/757743/what-is-the-difference-between-builder-design-pattern-and-factory-design-pattern

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a Factory Method. The naming convention leads you to think it's the builder pattern which has a separate object for the building of the concrete object. You have a separate object but are not setting the data like a builder would.

I'm not too familiar with PHP but to make it a builder pattern you'd create methods for the data, then call create()/build() at the end of the method chain.

It's creation would look like this

```
$objInstance = (new BusinessObject())->number($number)->create();
```

Since you only have a class with a method that creates an object, this pattern falls into the factory method category. Usually you use a builder when there are a lot of potential different configurations of an object upon creation, so you may just stick the factory method, if you only are setting one piece of data.

[Builder Pattern](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/builder/php/1)

Comment: well in my application I am setting up several pieces -- model name, various input parameters, and other data. It is done at the same time (i.e. all data is known at the same point in time)