# Private members in Enum Java

Tags: java, enums

```
public class Test {

    public static enum MyEnum {
        valueA(1),valueb(2),valuec(3),valued(4);
        private int i;
        private Object o;

        private MyEnum(int number) {
             i = number;
        }

        public void set(Object o) {
            this.o = o;
        }

        public Object get() {
            return o;
        }


     } 

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(MyEnum.valueA.i); // private
    }
}
```

output: 1

Why 1 is shown if it a private member in enum?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1801718/why-can-outer-java-classes-access-inner-class-private-members

Comment: By convention, enums are always uppercase!

Comment: private means visible to the class only, but this is exactly what you have.

Answer (score 5):

Outer classes have full access to the member variables of their inner classes, therefore
`i` is visible in the `Test` class.

In contrast, if `MyEnum` was external to the `Test` class, the compiler would complain about the visibility of `i`,

Answer (score 3):

It's (i) a member field being referenced within the same class (MyEnum); no access modifier prevents that - the private access modifier defined on i will prevent it's visibility outside this class.
[Suggested Reading](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html)

Answer (score 1):

private access from a containing type to a nested type is permitted, see [Why are private fields on an enum type visible to the containing class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5069374/why-are-private-fields-on-an-enum-type-visible-to-the-containing-class)

Answer (score 0):

`vlaueA` is considered a static variable so you can call it within `MyEnum` since `i` in the 
same `enum` whice play the same as a class so `MyEnum` can access `valueA` which can access `i`

Answer (score 0):

Outer class will have the access to inner class member even if it is private because you have defined `main` method inside the outer class.