# Available private variables

Tags: java, class, undefined-behavior

I've written a very small class [that have to grow!] but I suddenly see something "strange".

This is the class:

```
class Chara{
  private boolean flag_loaded;
  private boolean flag_rage, flag_shield;
  private int int_rage, int_shield;
  Chara(String fileName){
    flag_loaded = true
    if(flag_loaded){
      flag_rage = false;
      int_rage = 0;
      flag_shield = false;
      int_shield = 0;
    }
  }
  boolean rage(){return flag_rage;}
  boolean shield(){return flag_shield;}
  void add_rage(int toAdd){flag_rage = Bool(int_rage += limitMin(toAdd, 0));}
  void add_shield(int toAdd){flag_shield = Bool(int_shield += limitMin(toAdd, 0));}
  void sub_rage(int toAdd){flag_rage = Bool(int_rage -= limitMin(toAdd, 0));}
  void sub_shield(int toAdd){flag_shield = Bool(int_shield -= limitMin(toAdd, 0));}
```

As you can see all the variables are set as `private`.

NOTE: `limitMin()` return the same type variable, in this case `0` if `toAdd` is lower. Bool() is simply a cast.

This is a piece of main:

```
Chara chara = new Chara("lol");
print(chara.int_shield, (chara.shield()) ? COL_GREEN : COL_RED);
print(chara.flag_shield, (chara.shield()) ? COL_GREEN : COL_RED);
```

Nothing is done between declaration, instance and printing.

This piece of code is supposed to print in green the value of the shield and if there is or not the shield but it should not print anything because of `int_shield` and `flag_shield` that are supposed to be `private`.

The result is a nice `0` and a nice `false` in red...

Why is this happening?
I am doing something wrong?

In despair I tried making the variables `protected` but as I expected nothing happened.

EDIT: added entire Chara class.

Comment: What is the `Chara();` line in your code supposed to do?

Comment: Setting everything to 0 [for `int`s] and false [for `boolean`s]

Comment: Why? That's what happens by default. How is that even syntactically valid...?

Comment: @MattBall call them "debugging purposes", now the problem is why I can access private variables!

Comment: I would guess that main() is in your class, and can therefore access the variables.  Don't post any more explanations or code snippets -- boil down the above to a runnable class, and run it.  2-to-1 you will then see the answer yourself; if not, you will have something reasonable to post here.

Comment: No, the structure is Class{subclass{}; main();} and main can read subclass variables.

Comment: @IngrossoD In that case, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1801718/why-can-outer-java-classes-access-inner-class-private-members should help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `main` method *must* be declared in your `Chara` class, or in some enclosing class of the `Chara` class.  That would explain why it can access the `private` fields of a `Chara` instance directly.  The Java access rules would prevent access to a `private` variable in all other circumstances.

An inner / nested class is allowed to access the private variables of an enclosing class, and *vice versa*.  (At least, it is allowed from the perspective of the "access" rules.  There are various other rules that may prevent / limit this.)

I'm sure there is no "undefined behaviour" here.  Just behaviour that you don't understand.

---

If this does not explain the behaviour, I don't understand your question / what your code really looks like.  Please replace the code snippets on your Question with an SSCCE if you want further help.

Comment: @Dennis Meng made my day, thanks to all of you guys!