# Why can the private member of an nested class be accessed by the methods of the enclosing class?

Tags: java

Could anyone tell me about the accessing level of private member? I have been confused with this piece code for quite a long time: why the private member, k of Line class, can be accessed in "print" method of outter class?

```
public class myClass {
    public static class Line{
        private double k;
        private double b;
        private boolean isVertical;

        public Line(double k, double b, boolean isVertical){
            this.k = k;
            this.b = b;
            this.isVertical = isVertical;
        }

    }

    public static boolean print(Line line){
        System.out.println(line.k);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 45, accepted):

The rules are in the [JLS chapter on accessibility](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.6.1)

> Otherwise, if the member or constructor is declared `private`, then
>   access is permitted if and only if it occurs **within the body of the
>   top level class (§7.6) that encloses the declaration of the member or
>   constructor.**

Here the member field `k` is declared in the class `Line`. When you access it in the `print` method, you are accessing it *within the body of the top level class that encloses the declaration* of that member.

The chapter on top level classes is [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-7.html#jls-7.6).