# Designing DTOs as inner classes

Tags: java, design-patterns, architecture, dto

Is it ok to design DTOs/parameter wrapper objects as inner classes? Is it common practice or does it have any major drawbacks? E.g:

```
//I want to initiate threads with parameters
public class TradeBot implements Callable<TradingReport> {

//I have a few parameters, so I decided to wrap those into an object
TradeBotParamDTO params;

//the wrapper for parameters is actually an inner class:
public class TradeBotParamDTO {
    JsonNode config;
    Instrument instrument;
    TimeframeBarMQL tf;
    int numberOfBars;
    int port;
    String host;

}

//Constructor to instantiate the Runnable with parameters
public TradeBot(TradeBotParamDTO params) {
    super();
    this.params = params;
}


@Override
public TradingReport call() {
//access params here...
params.getXXX()
... 
}
}
```

Comment: If the wrapper object isn't used anywhere else, I see nothing wrong with it, other than the fact that your classes might end up a bit big and bloated.  Have you considered the Builder pattern (https://dzone.com/articles/design-patterns-the-builder-pattern)?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19826278/1371329