# Why does nesting a class give the containing class access to the child class' protected data?

Tags: class, delphi, scope

The question may be a bit confusing, and is best illustrated by an example:

```pascal
unit Test
interface
type
  TestClass = class()
    Splitter1: TcxSplitter;
    procedure SomeMethod();
  end;

implementation
uses
  cxSplitter;

// Locally-declared child type
type
  TcxSplitterAccess = class(TcxSplitter);

procedure TestClass.SomeMethod()
var
  pos: integer;
begin
  // Access to protected field FPositionBeforeClose by casting
  pos := TcxSplitterAccess(Splitter1).FPositionBeforeClose;
end;
```

Notice in the implementation section that there is a type `TcxSplitterAccess` being declared as a child of the `TcxSplitter` class. In the method `SomeMethod()`, belonging to the class `TestClass`, a `TcxSplitter` object is cast to the locally-declared `TcxSplitterAccess` class, and then a protected field is accessed on that object.

This is surprising to me as someone coming from a background of languages like Java, C++, C#, etc. In those languages, it is possible to access protected data in an object so long as you are doing it from *within that object's type or an inherited type*. For example, a method inside of a class `ClazzA` can access the private fields of other `ClazzA` objects since access is enforced at the *type* level rather than the *instance* level. Declaring a class locally in these languages would not give the containing class access to the local class' protected data (**edit:** As pointed out in the comments, this is actually not true at least for Java).

In this example, however, the type `TestClass` is directly accessing a protected field on the `TcxSplitter` object by first casting to the `TcxSplitterAccess` type. I am having trouble finding documentation on why this "trick" works. Does Delphi handle access levels fundamentally differently to Java-like languages and allows this sort of thing? Regardless, why does this trick work?

While I stumbled onto this behavior by using a nested, inherited class in order to access fields on the parent class (which breaks encapsulation, and I shouldn't do), the use of inheritance here is unnecessary. If the nested class did not inherit from a class, but instead had its own protected fields defined, `TestClass` would still be able to access those protected fields.

Comment: Can't give an accurate answer without seeing the source for TcxSplitter. Is FPositionBeforeClose truly Private, or is it Protected? I'm pretty sure if you create a descendant of a class in Java, it has access to protected fields

Comment: @DaveNottage I dug into the source, and you are correct - `FPositionBeforeClose` is actually a protected member. I've updated the question to reflect that. The question still stands however - notice in the example that the protected member is being accessed by `TestClass`, not by `TcxSplitterAccess`.

Comment: FWIW: Java and C# both allow nested/inner types access to private fields in the containing class. Java can also access the private members of the inner class from the containing class. Private rules (not polymorphic) are entirely separate from protected rules. — https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/nested-types (C#), https://stackoverflow.com/q/1801718/2864740 (Java)

Comment: @user2864740 I was aware of nested classes having access to the containing class' private data, but this situation is the reverse of that. I had no idea that Java could do this as well! If that is the case, then it might simply be that this pattern isn't so unusual and I was just unaware of it.

Comment: *"it is possible to access protected data in an object so long as you are doing it from - within that object's type or an inherited type"* - This is exactly what you're doing here, "TcxSplitterAccess" inherits from "TcxSplitter" and thus it can access protected members of the latter.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz Ah, be careful here, as there is a subtle difference that sets this apart from normal inheritance behavior. It is not `TcxSplitterAccess` that is accessing the protected data, it is actually `TestClass` that is accessing the protected member *on* `TcxSplitterAccess` (and by extension, `TcxSplitter`). `TestClass` contains the (nested) definition, it is not actually a parent.

Comment: Indeed I don't understand that difference, LHS is irrelevant - the inherited class is accessing the protected member..

Comment: The child class (`TcxSplitterAccess`) is in fact *not* accessing the protected member in this example - the method's full declaration is `TestClass.SomeMethod`, which means that we are operating within the `TestClass` type. So it is in fact `TestClass` that is accessing the protected member `FPositionBeforeClose` *on* the class `TcxSplitterAccess`, from which TestClass is not descended. Consider what would happen if that line was instead, `pos := Splitter1.FPositionBeforeClose;`. This results in a compile-time error since `TestClass` can not access `TcxSplitter` protected members.

Comment: Where we are operating is irrelevant, that was what I attempted to mean by LHS. "pos := Splitter1.FPositionBeforeClose;" this results in a compile time error not because testclass cannot access tcxsplitter protected members but because "splitter1" cannot access protected members because it's of type tcxsplitter.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222627/discussion-between-zach-f-and-sertac-akyuz).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `unit` has implicit-friendship semantics within itself.  Types *declared in the same `unit`* are "friends" of each other (similar to `friend` in C++), and so can access each other's `private` and `protected` members (but not `strict private` or `strict protected` members).

So, in this case:

- `TcxSplitterAccess` derives from `TcxSplitter`, so `TcxSplitterAccess` inherits all of the `protected` (but not `private`) members of `TcxSplitter` via normal class inheritance.
- `TestClass` is declared in the same `unit` as `TcxSplitterAccess`, so `TestClass` has access to all of the `protected` members of `TcxSplitterAccess`, *including* the `protected` members of `TcxSplitter` (and the `protected` members of its ancestors).
- `FPositionBeforeClose` is `protected` in `TcxSplitter`.

So, that is why `TestClass.SomeMethod()` is able to access `FPositionBeforeClose` when type-casting the `Splitter1` object to `TcxSplitterAccess`.

This is covered by the Delphi documentation:

[Private, Protected, Public, and Published Declarations](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Private,_Protected,_Public,_and_Published_Declarations)

[Classes and Objects (Delphi): Visibility of Class Members](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Classes_and_Objects_(Delphi)#Visibility_of_Class_Members)

Comment: `Strict` is the keyword that I was not searching for that would have lead me directly to this conclusion. Thank you for pointing out that exception.