# When should I use builder Design Pattern?

Tags: design-patterns

I'm learning about Design Patterns and found the Builder design pattern. What are the benefits of this design pattern and when should I use it? I surf **www.dofactory.com** and **www.blackwasp.com** but still don't understand the benefits.  By the by, I'm new to design patterns so please explain me with simple ones.

Comment: possible duplicate of [When would you use the Builder Pattern?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/328496/when-would-you-use-the-builder-pattern)

Comment: Also check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5674513/differences-between-builder-pattern-vs-template-method

Comment: Why are the most interesting questions always closed on SO?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The Builder Design Pattern helps us to slice the operations of building an object. It focuses on constructing a complex object step by step. It also enforces a process to create an object as a finished product. That means an object has to be massaged by some instructed steps before it is ready and can be used by others.

Generally, It allows you to encapsulate the complex create logic.

Builder pattern is very much like factory pattern. The key difference between a builder and factory is that a builder is useful when you need to do lots of things to build an object.

For more information:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/architecture/Builder_Design_Pattern.aspx

Comment: Simple wordings play better, Thanks for this.

Answer (score 5):

Builder design pattern helps to hide the complex logic in the builder class. Suppose we are developing a solution which constructs a large football field in different season as chosen by application users. We will create a builder class and pass the season info object in the builder class. Then the builder class is responsible construct the field according to seasons.

Answer (score 2):

Builder Design Pattern is USED when we wants instance to perform specific tasks in specific order see [wiki Builder pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern) for details.

Hopes that helps

Answer (score 2):

Have you checked [Wikipedia Builder page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern)?

> The intention is to abstract steps of
>   construction of objects so that
>   different implementations of these
>   steps can construct different
>   representations of objects.

Wikipedia example in Java. That should help.

Comment: the example doesn't seem to involve pizza anymore :)

Comment: @DavidDoria thank you for pointing out that someone ate the Wikipedia Pizza, and now the example is no longer available :) I updated my post