# Is there a way to make an argument in a constructor optional?

Tags: java

I am writing a simple inventory system for practice and I have an item class that holds these values:

```
private String name;
private int quantity;
private Integer ID;
private Double pricePerUnit;
private Double totalPrice;
```

I am writing the constructors for this class and I want everything except the name and quantity to be optional, as in the user can opt whether or not to input any data for those fields. Currently I have two constructors that look like this:

```
public Item(String name, int quantity)
{
    this.name=name;
    this.quantity=quantity;
}

public Item(String name, int quantity, Integer ID, Double pricePerUnit, Double totalPrice)
{
    this(name, quantity);
    this.ID=ID;
    this.pricePerUnit=pricePerUnit;
    this.totalPrice=totalPrice;
}
```

Is there any way I can make some of the arguments in the second constructor optional, or non-mandatory?

Thanks!

Comment: You can use builder design pattern to handle object initialization. https://stackoverflow.com/a/5788294/7505731

Answer (score 1):

Naturally, in such cases I'd would think of two possibilities to get what you need, `Constructor Overloading` and `Builder Pattern`

Although when you have the same data formats, You can't naturally depend on the former. In such cases (as OP's Question) the best alternative is to go for a builder design pattern.

You can build an instance of `Item.class` as the following

```
public class Item {



\\... other public functions.. etc


 static class ItemBuilder{

    private Item item;

    public ItemBuilder withNameAndQuantity(String name, int quantity){
      item = new Item(); //default constructor or as per your usecase a private constructor
      item.setName(name);
      item.setQuantity(quantity);
      return this;
    }

    public ItemBuilder withPricePerUnit(Double pricePerUnit){
      if(item!=null){
       item.setPriceUnit(pricePerUnit);
      }
      return this;
    }

    public ItemBuilder withTotalPrice(Double totalPrice){
      if(item!=null){
        item.setTotalPrice(totalPrice);
      }
      return this;
    }

   public Item build(){
    if(item!=null){
      return item;
    }else{
      throw new IllegalStateException("item is null, no name or id set");
    }
   }
 }
}
```

Finally, you could build a new Item by doing the following :

```
Item item = new Item.ItemBuilder(). withNameAndQuantity("apple",10). withTotalPrice(100).build();
```

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you would decompose the class into coherent pieces, in much the same way as you might normalise a database schema.

There is the *Builder Pattern*.

You code could be written better by making the constructor will all the attributes the "canonical constructor* and forward to that. This will also make it easier to switch over to records when they become available.

```
public Item(String name, int quantity) {
    this(name, quantity, null, null, null);
}

public Item(String name, int quantity, Integer id, Double pricePerUnit, Double totalPrice) {
    this.name = name;
    this.quantity = quantity;
    this.ID = ID;
    this.pricePerUnit = pricePerUnit;
    this.totalPrice = totalPrice; // Shouldn't this be calculated?
}
```

(Not that `null`s are ideal.)

Answer (score 0):

One way is to create more constructors and another is to loose the immutability and introduce setter methods.

Hence, you can use **Builder Pattern** as Builder Pattern will help you to consume additional attributes while retaining the immutability of Item class.

Below is the coded solution. This uses a additional class ItemBuilder which helps us in building desired Item object with all mandatory attributes and combination of optional attributes, without loosing the immutability.

```
public class Item {
    //All final attributes
    private String name; // required
    private int quantity; // required
    private Integer ID; // optional
    private Double pricePerUnit; // optional
    private Double totalPrice; // optional
 
    private Item(ItemBuilder builder) {
        this.name = builder.name;
        this.quantity = builder.quantity;
        this.ID = builder.ID;
        this.pricePerUnit = builder.pricePerUnit;
        this.totalPrice = builder.totalPrice;
    }
 
    //All getter, and NO setter to provide immutability
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public int getQuantity() {
        return quantity;
    }
    public Integer getID() {
        return ID;
    }
    public Double getPricePerUnit() {
        return pricePerUnit;
    }
    public Double getTotalPrice() {
        return totalPrice;
    }
 
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "User: "+this.name+", "+this.quantity+", "+this.ID+", "+this.pricePerUnit+", "+this.totalPrice;
    }
 
    public static class ItemBuilder
    {
        private String name; // required
        private int quantity; // required
        private Integer ID; // optional
        private Double pricePerUnit; // optional
        private Double totalPrice; // optional
 
        public ItemBuilder(String name, int quantity) {
            this.name = name;
            this.quantity = quantity;
        }
        public ItemBuilder ID(Integer ID) {
            this.ID = ID;
            return this;
        }
        public ItemBuilder pricePerUnit(Double pricePerUnit) {
            this.pricePerUnit = pricePerUnit;
            return this;
        }
        public ItemBuilder totalPrice(Double totalPrice) {
            this.totalPrice = totalPrice;
            return this;
        }
        //Return the finally constructed Item object
        public Item build() {
            Item item =  new Item(this);
            validateUserObject(item);
            return item;
        }
        private void validateUserObject(Item item) {
            //Do some basic validations to check 
            //if item object does not break any assumption of system
        }
    }
}
```

OR

You can also make use of JsonProperties.

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public record Item(
        String name,
        Integer quantity,
        @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL) Integer ID,
        @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL) Double pricePerUnit,
        @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL) Double totalPrice) {}
```

I hope this gives you clarity on how to resolve your problem.