# Java overridable call in constructor

Tags: java, methods, constructor, overriding, encapsulation

I know it is a bad (security) practice to call overridable methods from an object constructor in Java. However, for example, if the constructor has to initialize some data, it seems reasonable to call the respective setter method so that I don't copy code. The setters are public and not final. Is there any standard way of dealing with this, like declaring private setter methods, that the public ones call? To illustrate, here is some code:

```
class A {
    private double x,y;
    private privateSetX(double x1) { x=x1; }
    private privateSetY(double y1) { y=y1; }
    public A() { privateSetX(0); privateSetY(0); }
    public setX(double x1) { privateSetX(x1); }
    public setY(double y1) { privateSetY(y1); }
};
```

Comment: Presumably in this instance you wouldn't want to override the setters anyway?  In which case they should be declared `final`.

Comment: Oli really hit this on the head. It begs the question of if you should even have public setters, but instead have only private setters and have public external-interacting behaviors (you know, when `A` class goes and "A-ifies things" or whatever it does) that call the setters.

Comment: @Oli Well, so it happens that this class is generic enough that I would want it to be possible for it to be subclassed and the methods - overridable, so I didn't make the setters `final`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you *really* want to do this, create a secondary private setter method that is called by both the constructor and the public setter.

Comment: Oh, and one of the downsides of doing this is that you cannot have `final` instance fields.

Comment: @Oli: Yes, as in the given snippet. Just confirming. I don't recommend this as a matter of best practice, however.

Comment: @NathanRyan - It's hard to imagine a `final` instance field that would also have a setter. :)

Comment: @TedHopp That depends a bit on your coding standards. With a final instance field, the compiler is not able to determine the definite assignment, so the assignment statement in the setter would be flagged as a compiler error. But I've seen coding standards that require fields to be initialized via a setter in order to enable injection and/or instrumentation, despite the fact that these fields are final in practice. Whether these coding standards are appropriate is another matter :-)

Comment: There's a big difference between a `final` field (one declared with the keyword, which is what I was talking about) and a "final in practice" field. If a coding standard requires that a field be initialized via a setter, then the field simply cannot be declared `final`. Likewise (as you noted) there's just no getting around that the compiler won't allow a field declared `final` to also have a setter. Of course, with a builder pattern (as in @shoover's answer), one can have both: a `final` field that is initialized through a setter (which would then be in the builder class).

Comment: Oh, one issue with your answer (+1, btw), is that any subclass setter will need to call through to the superclass setter if proper behavior is to be maintained. Java, unfortunately, doesn't have any built-in way of enforcing this.

Answer (score 2):

I think that initialising the data members *directly* in the constructor is better practice. If you call a method, then you have to go look at that method implementation to verify that it really is doing what it looks like it's doing. If you assign to a data member directly, you *know* that the initialisation is taking place. So in your code:

```
class A {
    private double x, y;
    public A() {
        x = 0;
        y = 0;
    }
    // ...
}
```

A constructor should usually be simple, deterministic, and obviously correct. Direct assignment satisfies these goals.

Comment: Does not seem to be very DRY to me, either. Setters could do stuff like sanitizing input, etc. We would need to do the same in the constructor.

Comment: What's the aversion to duplicating a *single* assignment statement? The assignment in the constructor is *initialisation*, and the assignment in a setter method is *changing* an existing value. They're different purposes.

Comment: @K.Steff: Here's something that you may want to do instead, as a matter of better practice: Leave the individual assignments in the constructor and setters, and instead extract intermediate computation (like complex parameter validation) as separate, private methods.

Comment: @elusive Sanitize the input in package private static methods that have been unit tested and have no side effects.  Call these methods from both the constructor and the accessor/mutators.

Answer (score 2):

A better way to create an object that needs to have lots of different fields set during construction is to use the **Builder Pattern**.

Rather than duplicate the efforts of others, I will just point you to a [most excellent SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1953567/18356) on this topic.

If the problem is that you need to override setters during the constructor, you can create a hierarchy of Builders instead of, or in addition to, the hierarchy of the primary class that you're trying to build.