# Calling multiple methods in Java

Tags: java, class, methods, method-chaining

I found a new way of calling multiple methods in Java and I don't really understands what's happening behind:

```
public class NutritionFacts {
private final int servingSize;
private final int servings;
private final int calories;
private final int fat;
private final int sodium;
private final int carbohydrate;

public static class Builder {
    // Required parameters
    private final int servingSize;
    private final int servings;
    // Optional parameters - initialized to default values
    private int calories      = 0;
    private int fat           = 0;
    private int carbohydrate  = 0;
    private int sodium        = 0;
    public Builder(int servingSize, int servings) {
        this.servingSize = servingSize;
        this.servings    = servings;
    }
        public Builder calories(int val)
            { calories = val;      return this; }
        public Builder fat(int val)
            { fat = val;           return this; }
        public Builder carbohydrate(int val)
            { carbohydrate = val;  return this; }
        public Builder sodium(int val)
            { sodium = val;        return this; }
        public NutritionFacts build() {
            return new NutritionFacts(this);
        }
}  

    private NutritionFacts(Builder builder) {
        servingSize  = builder.servingSize;
        servings     = builder.servings;
        calories     = builder.calories;
    }

}
```

Now the class is instantiated using this line, and here's where it gets confusing:

```
NutritionFacts cocaCola = new NutritionFacts.Builder(240, 8).calories(100).sodium(35).carbohydrate(27).build();
```

It all makes sense till the NutritionFacts.Build(int, int), after that, what exactly is happening? Why do the `calories`, `sodium`, `carbohydrate` methods from Builder class need to return `this`? Where does that class adress go into?

Thank you!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It doesn't "go into" anything.

These methods return a value. In this case, they return the current instance, `this`. That instance has methods, like `calories()` and `carbohydrates()`.

`foo.calories(12)` returns the instance, and we can call its methods: `foo.calories(12).sodium(35)`.

It's no different than the "return value" from the constructor, implicitly defined as the new instance. In this case it's normal methods, still returning an instance--the current one.

It's the same as this:

```
Builder foo = new Builder(1, 2); // The "return" value of a ctor is the reference, foo
foo.sodium(10);   // Returns foo, but we ignore it
foo.calories(42); // Returns foo, but we ignore it

(foo.sodium(10)).calories(42);
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ foo, with the side effect of setting the sodium value
```

[Here's an SO question with some good examples.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/328496/when-would-you-use-the-builder-pattern)

Comment: Does this mean that the returned value from foo.calories(12), which is the instance, is used for calling the next method in line, in our case, sodium(35)?

Answer (score 3):

This is generally known as method chaining and it is a pretty common idea across OO:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining

Answer (score 2):

This technique is called "[method chaining](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining#Java)", and is a very nice style to get familiar with.  You do this instead of having to say something like:

```
NutritionFacts cocaCola = new NutritionFacts(240, 8, 100, 35, 27);
```

... which is prone to bugs, because the order or meaning of arguments in the constructor might change.  Or also instead of something like:

```
NutritionFacts cocaCola = new NutritionFacts(240, 8);
cocaCola.setCalories(100);
cocaCola.setSodium(35);
cocaCola.setCarbohydrates(27);
```

... which is bad for a few reasons: first because it's not as "[fluent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface)" in terms of legibility, second because the setters are called non-atomically (which is undesirable when the object is shared across multiple threads), and third because the `calories`, `sodium` and `carbohydrates` fields are *forced* to be non-`final`.  In the `Builder` variant, those fields can easily be made `final` because they are only set once in the constructor.

This pattern, in which every call to the `Builder` returns a reference to itself, lets you chain those calls to keep them easily readable, and to keep the construction of the resulting object atomic.

Answer (score 1):

You've defined `Builder` as a nested class of `NutritionFacts`. Since it's static, it doesn't require a `NutritionFacts` instance to exist. If it wasn't static (a so-called "inner class") it would require a NutritionFacts to exist. Also, some of your Builder fields would be hiding certain NutritionFact fields, but that isn't the case now.

Now, since you've used this nested class thingie, you can't just refer to it as `Builder`. You'll have to refer to it as `NutritionFacts.Builder`. So when in your second code extract you do `new NutritionFacts.Builder(240, 8)`, what you get is a new Builder instance with a servingSize 240 and 8 servings. NutritionFacts doesn't really come into play yet, it's only there for the name.

That newly create instance could be assigned to some variable, or it could be used immediately by, say, calling some method on it. That's what you're doing, namely you call `.calories(100)` on it which sets the calories field of that Builder. But if you go and take a look at that method, you'll notice it has return type Builder and what it ends up returning is `this`. The this keyword simply refers to the current instance: that very same Builder yet again.

The same then goes on for `.sodium(35)` and `.carbohydrate(27)`, after which you end up calling `.build()` on your Builder. Look at that method. It calls the NutritionFacts constructor. That constructor takes a Builder instance as an argument, and our Builder passes itself in (again with `this`). Now we're finally getting a NutritionFacts instance, and it is created using the values that were stored in the Builder instance.

Like Jere said, the methods that set the Builder nutrients use the method chaining approach to return the object they were called on, so that multiple methods can be conveniently chained together on a single line. In reality, your second extract could just as well be written like this:

```
NutritionFacts.Builder builder = new NutritionFacts.Builder(240, 8);
builder.calories(100);
builder.sodium(35);
builder.carbohydrate(27);
NutritionFacts cocaCola = builder.build();
```