# Alternative to Varargs

Tags: java, arrays, list, collections, variadic-functions

I'm implementing a class and its' constructor have to get some Strings as parameters, but I don't know the number of these Strings. I could here pass a vararg parameter (String), but it is a Homework, and we can't use any type of arrays or other uncommon librarys in our solution. (It should be an ArrayList or something likethat because we are learning now the Collections-Framework) I thought to pass a List as parameter to the constructor, but this list have to be filled before, and it's pretty long.. It should be simple.

So the first solution with varargs (which isn't accepted) should be something like:

```
public MyClass(String... myStrings) 
{
     for (String string : myStrings)
     {
          myStrings.add(string);
     }
}
```

So it will be usable like that for example:

```
MyClass example = new MyClass("String1", "String2", "String3");
```

or

```
MyClass example2 = new MyClass("String1", "String2");
```

The second one (which is a bit complicated, since the list should be "filled" before):

```
public MyClass(List<String> myStrings) 
{
      myPlayers = myStrings;
}
```

(ps: myPlayer is an instance-variable that will be then inizialized)

So do you have any idea (like the first one but without

Comment: String[] is first of all an Array, (and we can't use arrays in this homework, so we cannot use varargs neither) and it has to be filled before like my second solution with the List

Comment: What's wrong with the second one? If filling is really an option, use Arrays.asList(...) (yes, I know it's an array/varargs. I just don't see the 'complicated' part here.

Comment: so in the main class (and its' main method) I will have to make an ArrayList, to fill it with the different Strings, and then start a new Game with that list as parameter. I think it's pretty simple to have something like the 1st solution (like varargs but with lists) but it seems that there isn't something that fits to my goals.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short, my solution would be:

```
public MyClass(List<String> myStrings) 
{
      myPlayers = myStrings;
}
```

And then call it with:

```
List<String> items = new ArrayList<String>() {{ add("first"); add("second"); add("third"); }};
MyClass myClass = new MyClass(items);
```

No need for builders, just an anonymous subclass of ArrayList in which you'll call the add method of ArrayList. This way you can easily construct the list, without needing varargs/arrays.

Comment: Erik, can you point to a page which defines that syntax? It looks interesting, but I can't find a page which describes such a structure.

Comment: Arkanon, something like this you mean? http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?DoubleBraceInitialization

Comment: @ErikPragt Thank you, that confirms what I thought it was doing. I have to say your solution is the better one given that it provides exactly the functionality required using only native syntax.

Comment: I was going to say you should just do `List<String> items = Arrays.asList("first", "second", "third");`, but then realized that OP "can't use varargs". And then I thought `List<String> items = Arrays.asList(new String[]{"first", "second", "third"});`, but then realized that OP "can't use arrays" either! So ridiculous!

Answer (score 3):

Do some research into the Builder Pattern. There is a good discussion about it in the Stack Overflow question [When would you use the Builder Pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/328496/when-would-you-use-the-builder-pattern).

If you create a StringListBuilder class, you can simply have a method signature like this:

```
MyClass(List<String> stringList) {/* ... */}
```

and you can call the constructor using your builder class like this:

```
MyClass example = new MyClass(new StringListBuilder("first string").
        add("second string").add("third string").add("and so on").toList());
```

This will allow you to build a list of any size (including an empty list) without resorting to varargs or arrays.

Comment: Sure, but then you can (more easily) do List<String> x = new ArrayList<String>() {{ add("first"); add("second"); add("third"); }}; if that's really a problem.

Comment: Thankyou for your Answer Arkanon. I think it's the MOST suitable answer to my question. But I will use the other solution because I think it's right now faster to implement. Thankyou very much!

Comment: @KarimBelkhiria Thank you, but I think you should accept Erik Pragt's answer because it's more elegant and doesn't require the creation of any additional infrastructure classes.

Comment: I did! but couldn't do it before, because Stackoverflow doesn't allow to accept an answer when it is a real new one.. so I waited and accepted it after some minutes :)