# Best way to pass arguments in constructor

Tags: java, design-patterns

I have a class that create rows in table layout. The row creation depend upon data and metadata. As metadata is same for each row like show/hide visibility properties etc. so I have created metadata property as a static and initialize once using `initWidget` of `RowWidget`.

just example:

```
class RowWidget extends FlexTable{

  public static void initWidget(Form form,
    HashMap<Long, ContractorPermissionEnum> formModePermissionMap,
    GridMode gridMode,
    boolean isApplied,
    boolean isChildExist,
    boolean isChildAttachment)
    { 
      // ...
    }
}
```

Then I called below constructor for each record data.

```
public RowWidget(DataRawType dataRawType, Data data, Data parentData) {
 // ...
}
```

As I thought this is not right approach. because as pattern when anyone see this class then understand it will create one row. I don't want to call initially `initWidget`. I want to pass each required parameter in constructor only like

```
public RowWidget(DataRawType dataRawType,
  Data data,
  Data parentData,
  Form form,
  HashMap<Long, ContractorPermissionEnum> formModePermissionMap,
  GridMode gridMode,
  boolean isApplied,
  boolean isChildExist,
  boolean isChildAttachment) {
  // ...
}
```

But due to this, constructor have no of arguments. and I think it's also bad pattern to have 5+ parameter in constructor.

Is Anyone suggest me:

- How to construct class which have same property required in another
  instance?

**Note**:I know this is possible through static only but don't want to use static.

- What is best way to construct class with having some default fix
  property for all instances?

**Note**: I don't want to create another class to achieve it. or any getter/setter method.

Thanks In advance.

Comment: you could reduce the length of you parameter list a bit if you turned the boolean parameters into a `Map` or `Set` like you did with the form permissions

Comment: yeah I can. let's any one don't have another approch. I will go for it.

Comment: Well, if you realy don't want any new class, want to get rid of static and long parameter list, how about this **DIRTY** suggestion: use a `Map<String, Object>` to hold your parametrs, fill once and pass that map to `RowWidget` consturctor and get+cast them to use while constructing. This is worst than having long parameter list since last one is more explicite on what parameters the class is needing and more readable/maintainable. You should also reconsider your design. What holds you from introducing a new class?

Comment: @A4L hehe that was exactly my very first idea when i read the no-new-class-note but i didn't dare to suggest it ;)

Comment: @MarcoForberg hah... that's why it came only as comment ;-)

Comment: @A4L I agree with you this is worst cases.. and it's confuse.. that is way. I added this question in SO for clear my doubt from expert opinion. do you have any idea?

Comment: @Bhumika unfortunatly I can't think of any other ideas other than already here suggested for now :/

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest builder pattern. You would need one extra class to create RowWidget objects. So the call would look like that:

```
RowWidget widget = new RowWidget.Builder().withData(data).withParentData(parentData).withDataRawType(dataRawType).build();
```

Here is neat explanation of the pattern:https://stackoverflow.com/a/1953567/991164

Comment: But here there is a chance for missing thing

Comment: If you need to make sure none of the args is missing just perform a check in build() method and throw exception if it is.

Answer (score 0):

Why not create method which will accept the newValues for the properties you want to change & return a new instance of the classes with all other properties copied from the instance on which you invoked this method.

Answer (score 0):

> How to construct class which have same property required in another instance?

To achive this you can have a super class with all the properties you want. So any class extending this super class will be have these properties. This way you don't need to use `static` keyword.

> What is best way to construct class with having some default fix property for all instances?

For this one you can have an interface with some constant properties. This way any class implementing this interface will be having the fixed properties.

Comment: I know with super class but you please read my question. I don't need it. AFAIK super class needs when no of controls have same property. here I have only one control. and for initialize super class I need constructor. right? so also I have to pass argument some how there..right? how?

Comment: @Bhumika: Since you have same properties for several controls, then you can simply define them in the super class, so you will need just the default no-argument constructor.

Answer (score 0):

You could separate/extract the parameters from the `RowWidget`-class fro example in a `RowWidgetConfig`-class.

```
class RowWidgetConfig {
    // put here all your parameters that you need to initialize only once
    // init using setters
}
```

Now create once instance of that class and pass it among the other parameters to `RowWidget` constructor.

Another alternative would be to have `factory` for creating `RowWidget` instances. The factory would also contain all the parameters you need for a row instance plus a factory method `createNewRowWidget` witch creates an instance base on the parameters contained in the factory.

```
class RowWidgetFactory {
    // put here all your parameters that you need to initialize only once
    // init using setters

    public RowWidget createNewRowWidget() {
        // create
        return ...
    }
}
```

Comment: the OP said he didn't want another class. "Note: I don't want to create another class to achieve it."

Comment: @MarcoForberg oops, i missed that detail :/

Comment: but i have to admit that a config class was the first thing that sprung to my mind ;9

Comment: @MarcoForberg I am realy curious how this can be done! i'll be deleting this answer since it is not helpful for OP.

Comment: me too! I think a config class would be good, despite the fact he doesn't want a new class.

Answer (score 0):

The static initWidget() thing just doesn't seem right for me.  Though probably now you will only have one set of `RowWidget`s which share some properties, it is also reasonable to have 2 sets of `RowWidget`s, each set will have its own "shared" properties.  Things will be much more fluent and you have much more choices in building more reasonable APIs if you refactor your code to make a more reasonable design

Assume now I introduce something like a RowGroup (which kind of represents the "shared" thing you mentioned)

(Honestly I don't quite get the meaning for your design, I am just making it up base on your code);

```
public class RowGroup {
    public RowGroup(Form form,
                    HashMap<Long, ContractorPermissionEnum> formModePermissionMap,
                    GridMode gridMode,
                    boolean isApplied,
                    boolean isChildExist,
                    boolean isChildAttachment) { .... }

    public void addRow(DataRawType dataRawType, Data data, Data parentData) {...}
}
```

When people use, it looks something like:

```
RowGroup rowGroup = new RowGroup(form, permissionMap, gridMode, isApplied, isChildExist, isChildAttach);
rowGroup.addRow(DataRawType.A, dataA, parentA);
rowGroup.addRow(DataRawType.B, dataB, parentB);
```

You may even provide builder-like syntax or a lot other choices.

```
RowGroup rowGroup 
        = new RowGroup(.....)
              .addRow(DataRawType.A, dataA, parentA)
              .addRow(DataRawType.B, dataB, parentB);
```

Even more important, the design now make more sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

If you did not want to create another class, I'd suggest what A4L suggested.
Without creating another class, I would create constructor that takes all parameters and factory method that uses current instance as template and pass its own parameters to constructor parameter.

example (with obvious parts ommited)

```
class A{
  public A(int p1, int p2){...}
  public A create(int p2) {
    return new A(this.p1,p2);
}
```