# Construct object with many private collection fields

Tags: java, constructor, coding-style

What is the most **efficient** and **clean** way to create an object of a class that has like 10 private fields that are collections (eg. HashMap, LinkedHashMap, ArrayList etc).

If I put a constructor with 10 fields in it it would look like nightmare.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [Builder](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern) for that like this:

```
public class Pojo {

    private String field1;
    private String field2;
    private String field3;
    private String field4;
    private String field5;

    public Pojo(PojoBuilder pojoBuilder) {
        this.field1 = pojoBuilder.field1;
        this.field2 = pojoBuilder.field2;
        this.field3 = pojoBuilder.field3;
        this.field4 = pojoBuilder.field4;
        this.field5 = pojoBuilder.field5;
    }

    public static class PojoBuilder {
        String field1;
        String field2;
        String field3;
        String field4;
        String field5;

        public PojoBuilder field1(String field1) {
            this.field1 = field1;
            return this;
        }

        public PojoBuilder field2(String field2) {
            this.field2 = field2;
            return this;
        }
        public PojoBuilder field3(String field3) {
            this.field3 = field3;
            return this;
        }
        public PojoBuilder field4(String field4) {
            this.field4 = field4;
            return this;
        }
        public PojoBuilder field5(String field5) {
            this.field5 = field5;
            return this;
        }

        public Pojo build() {
            return new Pojo(this);
        }

    }

    public String getField1() {
        return field1;
    }

    public String getField2() {
        return field2;
    }

    public String getField3() {
        return field3;
    }

    public String getField4() {
        return field4;
    }

    public String getField5() {
        return field5;
    }


}
```

And you can use it like this:

```
Pojo pojo = new PojoBuilder().field1("field1").field1("field2").field1("field3").field1("field4").field1("field5").build();
```

I often use this pattern for building immutable pojos as well.

Comment: Why do you use final for fields here? What if you want to reuse this object later?

Comment: It is an example of how I usually use it but thanks for pointing it out I'll remove them.

Comment: Boo for removing them.  Keep final in!

Answer (score 2):

How about a [Builder pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern)

```
YourClass obj = YourClass.setCollection1(...)
                           .setCollection2(...)
                             .setCollection3(...)......
                                                  .build();
```

The added advantage is you just pass the required values and the rest will keep their default values.

Answer (score 0):

Consider [Builder Pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/328496/when-would-you-use-the-builder-pattern)

```
YourClass classObject = new YourClass.name("someName").age(26).Sex("M").build();
```