# How can I initialize a class without a constructor?

Tags: java, constructor, initialization

So I have this Contructor:

```
 public MyClass(boolean done, int lvl , String s, int x, int y, Skill parent, Item item, int cost) {
    this.done = done;
    this.lvl = lvl;
    this.name = s;
    this.Xpos = x;
    this.Ypos = y;
    this.parent = parent;
    this.item = item;
    addSkill(this, s);
}
```

Is there a way for me to use/initialize this in another class without having to do

```
MyClass myclass = new MyClass(false, 0, "", 0, 0, null, this.item, 1)
```

If I just do

```
MyClass myclass;
```

Then I get the "horrid" null pointer exception.

Comment: Create a parameter-less second constructor?

Comment: You can use `Dependency Injection` or create a factory method

Comment: write another constructor that invokes that one, providing some default arguments.

Comment: I think you misunderstand what the left hand side, `MyClass myclass`, is doing. You are declaring space in memory to fit an object of the `MyClass` size. You're calling the location of this space `myclass`. But you're not _putting_ anything in that space. It's null - thus the null pointer exception. You need to construct an object and assign it to that space (eg. `MyClass myclass = new MyClass();`). The only way you can make an object is to construct it - so you can never initialize a class without a constructor.

Comment: `MyClass myclass` is just a reference.  If you want an instance of an object, you have to create one.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you want to create a second constructor that takes no parameters.

You can then write

```
MyClass myclass = new MyClass();
```

Comment: Would the constructor just be a blank field?

Comment: @Snhp9 It would call your current constructor with the default values. However, note that you probably need at least one parameter, since there's an object reference being passed in for `item`.

Comment: may I post in a comment the class that I am dealing with?

Comment: @Snhp9 you need to declare the 0-pm constructor in your class before using it.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you implement something akin to the [Builder Pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1953567/2591612). It is very versatile. You can read more about the [Builder Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern) on Wikipedia.

Answer (score 0):

`MyClass myclass;` is just a reference. You need to bind it with some object. No use of remote  control without television. What else you can try to short your constructor is just provide a 0 parameter constructor.

```
 public MyClass() {
    this.done = "default";
    this.lvl = "default value";
    this.name = "default value";
    this.Xpos = "default value";
    this.Ypos = "default value";
    this.parent = "default value";
    this.item = "default value";
}
```

Now you can do like this `MyClass mcRef=new MyClass();`

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you might want some "default arguments". In Python, you could do something like this:

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(done=false, load=1, ...):
        self.done = done
        self.load = load
        # ...

a_new_instance = MyClass(done=true)
```

Basically, all of your variables start out with a default value - *but* you can change them if you are so inclined.

In Java, it is a little different:

```
class MyClass {
    private boolean done = false; // Notice the default value for done will be false
    // ... you would list (and instantiate!) the rest of your variables

    public MyClass() {}

    public MyClass(boolean done, int lvl, ...) {
         this.done = done;
         // ...
    }
}
```

In this way, you are only forced to call the constructor if you want to change the default values. But what happens if you only want to change 1 or 2 values? Well, you could make new constructors:

```
public MyClass(boolean done) { this.done = done; }
public MyClass(boolean done, int lvl) { this.done = done; this.lvl = lvl; }
```

but this will quickly get out of hand!

So, to get around this, we can use a "builder" pattern. That will look something like this:

```
public class MyClass {
    private boolean done;
    private int lvl;

    // Now the constructor is private and takes a builder.
    private MyClass(MyClassBuilder builder) {
        // ... and your variables come from the ones you will build.
        this.done = builder.done;
        this.lvl = builder.lvl;
        // ...
    }

    public static class MyClassBuilder {
        // The builder also has the same members.
        private boolean done;
        private int lvl;

        // Notice that we return the builder, this allows us to chain calls.
        public MyClassBuilder done(boolean isDone) {
            this.done = isDone;
            return this;
        }   

        public MyClassBuilder level(int level) {
            this.lvl = level;
        }

        // And a method to build the object.
        public MyClass build() {
            MyClass mc = new MyClass();
            mc.done = this.done;
            mc.lvl = this.lvl;
            // ... copy over all your variables from the builder to the new class
            return mc;
        }
    }
}
```

So, now when we want to instantiate a `MyClass` object we can do this:

```
MyClass mc = MyClassBuilder.done(false);
```

or, we can chain the calls:

```
MyClass mc2 = MyClassBuilder.done(true).level(4). // ... you can go on for a while
```

---

As an aside, sometimes having more than three or four variables in a class is a sign that the class is doing too much. If the class has more than one "responsibility", you should break it up into a few smaller classes. Then you won't need a builder class.

Answer (score 0):

This is not C++. Default values for all references is `null`. If you do not use `new`, the object remains `null`.

There are several methods of initialization if you dislike multi-parameter constructors. You can have setters return `this` and chain initialization like:

`Person p = new Person().setAge(18).setName("Tom").setHeight(175);`

or even simply

`Person p = new Person().age(18).name("Tom").height(175);`

Such method is not very common but definitely is easy to read and difficult to make mistake with.

You can also use static factory methods, like

```
class Person {

  private Person() {} // mark as private to force  creation with static method

  public static Person create() {
    Person p = new Person();
    //fill default values?
    return p;
  }
}
```