# Modularity when using the Java Builder pattern?

Tags: java, design-patterns

I created a class following the [Java builder pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1953567/1107232) and it has been working great for me, however now I find myself needing a little more modularity. Can this be accomplished without scrapping the Builder?

For example I would like to build my Person objects with a configuration array of enums (or any other method that would let me customize the order and selection of fields). The values come in from various nested objects and I need certain fields at certain times in certain orders to create an output CSV.

```
public static enum FIELDS = { FIRST, MIDDLE, LAST }

List<FIELDS> fields = { FIRST, LAST } creates:
Person person = new Person.builder().first("john").last("doe").build();

List<FIELDS> fields = { LAST, FIRST, MIDDLE } creates:
Person person = new Person.builder().last("doe").first("john").middle("q").build();
```

Is it possible to do any kind of switch statements on an enum to construct a Person dynamically like this?

Comment: So you need to create your instance using a configuration array of enums? Or do you want to have several variants of a builder, with specific constraints?

Comment: @TheTerribleSwiftTomato a config array of enums (or any equivalent way), updated question to be more clear

Comment: alright, but one more thing is unclear. Where do you want to get your values from if all you have is enums mapping to fields?

Comment: @TheTerribleSwiftTomato Heh updated again, values come in from a csv and are passed to the method that constructs the Builder. This is a simplified version here, the real one has Lists of Objects and such, not a simple enum->fieldname mapping.

Comment: If you're loading data from a file, what's the point of a builder, which is for source-level creation?

Comment: @DaveNewton well actually the data comes in from assorted objects and I need to format it to go out to a csv, updated question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well you could do something like that; e.g.

```
   public Person list2Person(List<FIELDS> fields) {
       Builder builder = new Person.builder();
       for (Field field : fields) {
           switch (field) {
           case FIRST:
              builder.first(getValue(FIRST));
              break;
           case MIDDLE:
              builder.middle(getValue(MIDDLE));
              break;
           ...
           }
           return builder.build();
       }
   }
```

Of course, this assumes that you have some way to implement `getValue(FIELDS)`.

Comment: Wow guess I was really over-thinking that one, this is exactly what I needed. Thanks Stephen!

Answer (score 0):

The work should be done inside the `enum` itself, probably. You can declare an `abstract` method in the main `enum` body and then override it in each `Enum` element.

```
import java.util.Iterator;

public class Person {
  public static enum FIELDS {
    FIRST ("john") { protected void addString(PersonBuilder builder) { builder.first(getName()); } },
    MIDDLE ("q") { protected void addString(PersonBuilder builder) { builder.middle(getName()); } },
    LAST ("doe") { protected void addString(PersonBuilder builder) { builder.last(getName()); } };

    private String name;

    protected abstract void addString(PersonBuilder builder);

    private FIELDS(String name) {
      this.name = name;
    }

    protected String getName() {
      return name;
    }
  }

  public static class PersonBuilder {
    public PersonBuilder addIterable(Iterable<FIELDS> iter) {
      Iterator<FIELDS> it = iter.iterator();
      while(it.hasNext()) {
        it.next().addString(this);
      }

      return this;
    }

    // you wrote these already, this is just to make it compile
    public void first(String first) { }
    public void middle(String middle) { }
    public void last(String last) { }
  }
}
```