# Pattern to render information in different ways

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns

I have a class RoomDesign which holds information about the measurements and color of the room for example. I need to be able to render this same information in different ways by a different class. Such as display it graphically with a diagram, or just simple with text. What is the best pattern to use for this kind of design.

Answer (score 2):

You should look into the [model-view-controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) pattern.

The views would be your renderers (diagram, text etc.) and the model would be your `RoomDesign` class or maybe a container for multiple room designs.

Answer (score 0):

If you view your `RoomDesign` as the Model part of Model-View-Controller (MVC), it pretty much speaks for itself. Just keep in mind not to store any purely visual-specific information in your model.

Answer (score 0):

Build and design a room. Aside from [model-view-pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller), you can take a look at [Builder](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern) pattern. Here's a good SO [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/328496/when-would-you-use-the-builder-pattern).

An [example](http://javapapers.com/design-patterns/builder-pattern/).