# How to avoid duplication of code regarding primitive types?

Tags: java, arrays, code-duplication

## Background

A bit input stream is backed by an array of bytes. There are a handful of methods that read from that byte array into various coerced primitive arrays.

## Problem

There is duplicated code. Java lacks generics on primitive types, so perhaps the repetition is unavoidable.

## Code

The repetitious code is apparent in the following methods:

```java
@Override
public long readBytes(final byte[] out, final int offset, final int count, final int bits) {
    final int total = offset + count;

    assert out != null;
    assert total <= out.length;

    final long startPosition = position();

    for (int i = offset; i < total; i++) {
        out[i] = readByte(bits);
    }

    return position() - startPosition;
}

@Override
public long readShorts(final short[] out, final int offset, final int count, final int bits) {
    final int total = offset + count;

    assert out != null;
    assert total <= out.length;

    final long startPosition = position();

    for (int i = offset; i < total; i++) {
        out[i] = readShort(bits);
    }

    return position() - startPosition;
}
```

Note how **`final byte[] out`** relates to **`readByte(bits)`** just as **`final short[] out`** relates to **`readShort(bits)`**. These relations are the crux of the problem.

## Question

How can the duplication be eliminated, if at all, without incurring a significant performance hit (e.g., by autoboxing)?

## Related

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/9666217/59087
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/27716039/59087
- https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/valhalla/Main
- https://www.slideshare.net/IvanIvanov138/primitives-in-generics-from-project-valhala

Comment: Nope, nothing you can do there. Duplication is the only option.

Comment: Use a third party primitive collection

Comment: `Java lacks generics on primitive types, so perhaps the repetition is unavoidable.` Yup.  (Usually it isn't much a problem, since it's rare for one program to need more than a few different primitives.  You could also "fix" this by putting primitives inside a class and using object serialization, although that can be relatively slow.)

Comment: @markspace and even if you need all primitives, there are only 8 of them. Code generation may be an option.

Comment: Also, (just remembered this) if you're reading bulk primitives like your code seems to indicate, using `ByteBuffer` methods like `asDoubleBuffer()` or `asShortBuffer()` will offload some of the lowest level work.  https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html

Comment: @Andy Turner And that is what exactly happened with `String.valueOf`, the overloaded method just was rewritten 9 times for different cases, just as an example (I know not each implementation is for a primitive).

Comment: Note that there are some efforts to bring primitive generic support to Java, i.e. `List<int>` etc. Release in maybe 2-5 years or so. It is called Project Valhalla.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're reading bulk primitives like your code seems to indicate, using [ByteBuffer](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html) methods like [asDoubleBuffer()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#asDoubleBuffer()) or [asShortBuffer()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#asShortBuffer()) will offload some of the lowest level work.

Example:

```
   public void readBytes( final byte[] out, final int offset, final int count, final ByteBuffer buffer ) {
      buffer.get( out, offset, count );  // udates ByteBuffer `position` automatically
   }

   public void readShorts( final short[] out, final int offset, final int count, final ByteBuffer buffer ) {
      ShortBuffer sb = buffer.asShortBuffer();
      sb.get( out, offset, count );  // note that `count` reads two bytes for each `short`
   }
```

(Code compiles but not tested!)

Answer (score 0):

One possibility, which will incur a performance penalty, is to use [`java.lang.reflect.Array`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Array.html#set(java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object)) to treat the array as an Object that then permits reusing the same code across all read methods.

```java
@FunctionalInterface
public interface BitArrayReader {
    Object read(int bits);
}

private long readPrimitive(
        final Object out, final int offset, final int count, final int bits,
        final BitArrayReader reader) {
    final int total = offset + count;

    assert out != null;
    assert total <= Array.getLength(out);

    final long startPosition = position();

    for (int i = offset; i < total; i++) {
        Array.set(out, i, reader.read(bits));
    }

    return position() - startPosition;
}

@Override
public long readBooleans(boolean[] out, int offset, int count, int bits) {
    return readPrimitive(out, offset, count, bits, this::readBoolean);
}
```

The duplication has been addressed at the cost of some performance, a minor lack of compile-time type safety, and use of reflection.