# Can't make Jackson and Lombok work together

Tags: java, netbeans, jackson, lombok

I am experimenting in combining Jackson and Lombok. Those are my classes:

```java
package testelombok;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonCreator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Value;
import lombok.experimental.Wither;

@Value
@Wither
@AllArgsConstructor(onConstructor=@__(@JsonCreator))
public class TestFoo {
    @JsonProperty("xoom")
    private String x;
    private int z;
}
```

```java
package testelombok;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.xebia.jacksonlombok.JacksonLombokAnnotationIntrospector;
import java.io.IOException;

public class TestLombok {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        TestFoo tf = new TestFoo("a", 5);
        System.out.println(tf.withX("b"));
        ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper().setAnnotationIntrospector(new JacksonLombokAnnotationIntrospector());
        System.out.println(om.writeValueAsString(tf));
        TestFoo tf2 = om.readValue(om.writeValueAsString(tf), TestFoo.class);
        System.out.println(tf2);
    }

}
```

Those are the JARs that I'm adding into the classpth:

- Lombok: https://projectlombok.org/downloads/lombok.jar (version 1.16.10)
- Jackson annotations: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-annotations/2.8.2/jackson-annotations-2.8.2.jar
- Jackson core: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-core/2.8.2/jackson-core-2.8.2.jar
- Jackson databind: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-databind/2.8.2/jackson-databind-2.8.2.jar
- Jackson-lombok: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/io/paradoxical/jackson-lombok/1.1/jackson-lombok-1.1.jar

I am compiling it with Netbeans (I don't think that this is really relevant, but I am reporting this anyway to make it perfectly and faithfully reproducible). The five JARs above are kept in a folder called "`lib`" inside the project folder (along with "`src`", "`nbproject`", "`test`" and "`build`"). I added them to Netbeans via the "*Add JAR/Folder*" button in the project properties and they are listed in the exact order as the list above. The project is a standard "Java application" type project.

Further, the Netbeans project is configured to "*do NOT compile on save*", "*generate debugging info*", "*report deprecated APIs*", "*track java dependencies*", "*activacte annotation proccessing*" and "*activacte annotation proccessing in the editor*". No annotation processor or annotation processing option is explicitly configured in Netbeans. Also, the "`-Xlint:all`" command line option is passed in the compiler command line, and the compiler runs on an external VM.

My javac's version is 1.8.0_72 and my java's version is 1.8.0_72-b15. My Netbeans is 8.1.

My project compiles fine. However, it throws an exception in its execution. The exception don't seems to be anything that looks easily or obvious fixable. Here is the output, including the stacktrace:

```
TestFoo(x=b, z=5)
{"z":5,"xoom":"a"}
Exception in thread "main" com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Argument #0 of constructor [constructor for testelombok.TestFoo, annotations: {interface java.beans.ConstructorProperties=@java.beans.ConstructorProperties(value=[x, z]), interface com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonCreator=@com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonCreator(mode=DEFAULT)}] has no property name annotation; must have name when multiple-parameter constructor annotated as Creator
 at [Source: {"z":5,"xoom":"a"}; line: 1, column: 1]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.from(JsonMappingException.java:296)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createAndCache2(DeserializerCache.java:269)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createAndCacheValueDeserializer(DeserializerCache.java:244)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache.findValueDeserializer(DeserializerCache.java:142)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.findRootValueDeserializer(DeserializationContext.java:475)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._findRootDeserializer(ObjectMapper.java:3890)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:3785)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2833)
    at testelombok.TestLombok.main(TestLombok.java:14)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Argument #0 of constructor [constructor for testelombok.TestFoo, annotations: {interface java.beans.ConstructorProperties=@java.beans.ConstructorProperties(value=[x, z]), interface com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonCreator=@com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonCreator(mode=DEFAULT)}] has no property name annotation; must have name when multiple-parameter constructor annotated as Creator
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BasicDeserializerFactory._addDeserializerConstructors(BasicDeserializerFactory.java:511)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BasicDeserializerFactory._constructDefaultValueInstantiator(BasicDeserializerFactory.java:323)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BasicDeserializerFactory.findValueInstantiator(BasicDeserializerFactory.java:253)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerFactory.buildBeanDeserializer(BeanDeserializerFactory.java:219)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerFactory.createBeanDeserializer(BeanDeserializerFactory.java:141)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createDeserializer2(DeserializerCache.java:406)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createDeserializer(DeserializerCache.java:352)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createAndCache2(DeserializerCache.java:264)
    ... 7 more
```

I already tried about randomly poking with the `@Value` and `@AllArgsConstructor` annotations, but I couldn't make it any better.

I google'd the exception and [found an old bug report on jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-datatype-jdk8/issues/16), and [another one that is open, but seems to be related to something else](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/1239). However, this still do not tells anything about what is this bug or how to fix it. Also, I could not find anything useful looking that somewhere else.

Since what I am trying to do is very basic usage of both lombok and jackson, it seems odd that I couldn't find any more useful information about how to workaround this issue. Maybe I missed something?

Other than just saying "*don't use lombok*" or "*don't use jackson*", do anybody has any idea about how to solve this?

Comment: Top answers to this question are a bit outdated. Please check out solution involving @Jacksonized annotation down below.

Comment: this works for me - https://github.com/projectlombok/lombok/issues/1563#issuecomment-362615072

Comment: @chimmi Top answers are a bit outdated, but an experimental feature will never go in any production environment.

Comment: First of all - quite a bold statement. And second, I was referring to @Jacksonized, which is not experimental.

Answer (score 86):

Immutable + Lombok + Jackson can be achieved in next way:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import lombok.AccessLevel;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Value;

@Value
@NoArgsConstructor(force = true, access = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
@AllArgsConstructor
public class LocationDto {

    double longitude;
    double latitude;
}

class ImmutableWithLombok {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

        String stringJsonRepresentation = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(new LocationDto(22.11, 33.33));
        System.out.println(stringJsonRepresentation);

        LocationDto locationDto = objectMapper.readValue(stringJsonRepresentation, LocationDto.class);
        System.out.println(locationDto);
    }
}
```

Comment: Isn't `AllArgsConstructor` already a part of `@Value` annotation?

Comment: Adding an explicit `@NoArgsConstructor` overrides the constructor which is generated by the `@Value` annotation, so you have to add the extra `@AllArgsConstructor`

Comment: Best solution I've found - in my opinion - without Builder pattern. Thanks.

Comment: Is adding `@AllArgsConstructor` "does" the `@JsonCreator` on the constructor for us? If yes, why do we need the `@NoArgsConstructor(force = true, access = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)`?

Comment: It is something I was looking for for a while! Replying to the last comment, you need both of them, that's why need `@NoArgsConstructor` but if you don't initialize the fields (force=true) you get an error when the `@NoArgsConstructor` annotation is set because fields are `final`

Comment: This works, but can anybody explain how can we still get an immutable class and NoArgsConstructor at the same time? If there are no setters, how Jackson proceeds to construct an object?

Comment: @Zon I tried with just `@Value @AllArgsConstructor` (without `@NoArgsConstructor`) and it works for me. If I put just `@Value` is not enough for jackson, so `@AllArgsConstructor` is doing something additional.

Comment: @Daniel in my case, `@Value @AllArgsConstructor` was enough

Comment: You think that class is immutable?

Answer (score 80):

If you want immutable but a json serializable POJO using lombok and jackson.
Use jacksons new annotation on your lomboks builder `@JsonPOJOBuilder(withPrefix = "")`
I tried this solution and it works very well.
Sample usage

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonDeserialize;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonPOJOBuilder;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Value;

@JsonDeserialize(builder = Detail.DetailBuilder.class)
@Value
@Builder
public class Detail {

    private String url;
    private String userName;
    private String password;
    private String scope;

    @JsonPOJOBuilder(withPrefix = "")
    public static class DetailBuilder {

    }
}
```

If you have too many classes with `@Builder` and you want don't want the boilerplate code empty annotation you can override the annotation interceptor to have empty `withPrefix`

```
mapper.setAnnotationIntrospector(new JacksonAnnotationIntrospector() {
        @Override
        public JsonPOJOBuilder.Value findPOJOBuilderConfig(AnnotatedClass ac) {
            if (ac.hasAnnotation(JsonPOJOBuilder.class)) {//If no annotation present use default as empty prefix
                return super.findPOJOBuilderConfig(ac);
            }
            return new JsonPOJOBuilder.Value("build", "");
        }
    });
```

And you can remove the empty builder class with `@JsonPOJOBuilder` annotation.

Comment: This solution keeps immutability whilst working around Jackson's brain-dead constructor based deserialisation issues (multi-field constructor requires @JsonProperty on each constructor argument, rather than trying something intelligent). (I had tried onConstructor_={@JsonCreator} without luck)

Comment: I am not sure, but I get the error `Builder class does not have the build method`.

Comment: how do you do the same with inherited subclasses?? The @Builder doesn't support adding field values for the parent class fields

Answer (score 38):

I tried several of the above and they were all temperamental.
What really worked for me is the the answer I found [here](https://github.com/rzwitserloot/lombok/issues/1563#issuecomment-358403046).

on your project's root directory add a [lombok.config](https://projectlombok.org/features/configuration) file (if you haven't done already)

> lombok.config

and inside paste this

```
lombok.anyConstructor.addConstructorProperties=true
```

Then you can define your pojos like the following:

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
public class MyPojo {

    @JsonProperty("Description")
    private String description;
    @JsonProperty("ErrorCode")
    private String errorCode;
}
```

Comment: But isn't this mutable?

Comment: to be immutable, just change data by Getter and Builder or  RequiredArgsConstructor and mark all fields as final

Comment: any ideas on why this is not working in my case? I have a spring boot application and I have placed lombok.config inside my src but still your solution is not working.

Comment: This config did not solve the problem for me, at least not in my unit tests.

Comment: Use [@Value](https://projectlombok.org/features/Value) instead of @Data to make it immutable.

Comment: Whilst this is a bad example because it's mutable - the property does help with OPs error. `@AllArgsConstructor(onConstructor=@__(@JsonCreator))` and `@Value` will work but only if you also have addConstructorProperties set to true.

Answer (score 28):

Here is an example by using
[`@Jacksonized`](https://projectlombok.org/features/experimental/Jacksonized) annotation:

```
import lombok.Value;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.extern.jackson.Jacksonized;

@Jacksonized
@Builder
@Value
public class User {
    String name;
    String surname;
}
```

It does require you to use `@Builder` annotation.

Comment: I think `@Value` may not be strictly necessary

Comment: but regardless, I think this is the simplest Answer :)

Comment: This works for `final` fields as well. By far the cleanest and simplest answer here, thanks!

Answer (score 8):

I had exactly the same issue, "solved" it by adding the `suppressConstructorProperties = true` parameter (using your example):

```
@Value
@Wither
@AllArgsConstructor(suppressConstructorProperties = true)
public class TestFoo {
    @JsonProperty("xoom")
    private String x;
    private int z;
}
```

Jackson apparently does not like the [`java.beans.ConstructorProperties`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/beans/ConstructorProperties.html)  annotation added to constructors. The `suppressConstructorProperties = true` parameter tells [Lombok](https://projectlombok.org/features/Constructor.html) not to add it (it does by default).

Comment: `suppressConstructorProperties` is now deprecated :-(

Comment: Which is not a problem, since the new default is also `false`.

Answer (score 8):

It can be done simpler, without extra annotations and the problem can be with the inheritance, i.e. child classes should be deserializable as well. So, my example:

Requirements:

`lombok.config` inside the project root directory with body containing:

```
lombok.anyConstructor.addConstructorProperties=true
```

```java
/** The parent class **/

@Value
@NonFinal
@SuperBuilder
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class Animal {
  String name;
}

/** The child class **/

@Value
@SuperBuilder
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class Cat {
  Long tailLength;
  
  @ConstructorProperties({"tailLength", "name})
  public Cat(Long tailLength, String name) {
      super(name);
      this.tailLength = tailLength;
  }
}
```

It:

1. Allows building of objects including fields of the parent
2. Serializes/Deserializes with the default `ObjectMapper` and Jackson
3. Instances of the parent and children classes are immutable

My advice against other examples:

1. Try not to put custom annotations on particular classes, it makes it *inhomogeneous*. Any way, you will come to a generic solution one day.
2. Try not to put `Jackson` annotations on any fields on constructors, it creates coupling, when Jackson is capable to serialize/deserialize without any annotations.
3. Do not use `@AllArgsConstructor` for immutable entities. When your class has only **final** fields, conceptually right is `@RequiredArgsConstructor`, that's how you guarantee that class-clients always will rely only on a constructor with the immutable entity. Will `@AllArgsConstructor` it might lead to passing nulls.

Comment: the best solution I've found, looks much clearer at least

Answer (score 6):

[From Jan Rieke's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55326612/2398020)

> Since lombok 1.18.4, you can configure what annotations are copied to
>   the constructor parameters. Insert this into your `lombok.config`:
>
> ```
> lombok.copyableAnnotations += com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty
> ```
>
> Then just add `@JsonProperty` to your fields:
>
> ...

You'll need a @JsonProperty on every field even if the name matches, but that is a good practice to follow anyway. You can also set your fields to public final using this, which I prefer over getters.

```java
@ToString
@EqualsAndHashCode
@Wither
@AllArgsConstructor(onConstructor=@__(@JsonCreator))
public class TestFoo {
    @JsonProperty("xoom")
    public final String x;
    @JsonProperty("z")
    public final int z;
}
```

It should also work with getters (+setters) though.

Comment: This solves my issue! Thank you so much!

I've been stuck on spring-boot-integration and serialization between JSON and POJOs and getting the error: `Can not deserialize instance of java.lang.String out of START_OBJECT token`... And this fixed it! I need to have that `@JsonProperty` annotation for each constructor parameter and that addition to the `@AllArgsConstructor` allows lombok to instrument that in.

Answer (score 5):

I found two options to solve this problem if you want to use `@Builder` with Jackson.

**Option 1**

- Add private default noArgs and allArgs constructors.

```
@Builder
@Getter
@Setter
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@AllArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
@NoArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
public class Person {

    @JsonProperty("user_name")
    private String name;
}
```

**Option 2**

Thanks to [this](https://www.thecuriousdev.org/lombok-builder-with-jackson/) article.

Jackson expects the builder methods to start like `.withProperty(...)` but Lombok generates `.property(...)`.

> What you can do is to create the builder class yourself so that you can add Jackson annotations to it. Lombok will then re-use this class and add all the builder methods to it.

```
@JsonDeserialize(builder = MyDto.MyDtoBuilder.class)
@Builder
@Getter
public class MyDto {

    @JsonProperty("user_id")
    private String userId;

    @JsonPOJOBuilder(withPrefix = "")
    @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
    public static class MyDtoBuilder {
    }
}
```

- You need to do some manual work
- Still much better than writing the Builder yourself
- Also note that additional properties like `@JsonIgnorePropertie` go on the builder

An additional drawback is that refactorings will not automatically rename the `MyDtoBuilder`. I hope in a future Lombok/Jackson version this issue is solved.

Update: I've found another solution (tested with lombok 1.18.20 and spring boot 2.4.5), added as Option 1.

Answer (score 5):

I have managed to keep my classes immutable and also deserialize them by using this lombok annotation:

```
@NoArgsConstructor(force = true)
```

Answer (score 4):

`@AllArgsConstructor(suppressConstructorProperties = true)` is deprecated. Define `lombok.anyConstructor.suppressConstructorProperties=true` (https://projectlombok.org/features/configuration) and change POJO's lombok annotation from `@Value` to `@Data` + `@NoArgsConstructor` + `@AllArgsConstructor` works for me.

Comment: This changes the class to be mutable, which I assume is not what OP wanted

Answer (score 3):

I've all my classes annotated like this:

```
@JsonAutoDetect(fieldVisibility = Visibility.ANY)
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_DEFAULT)
@Data
@Accessors(fluent = true)
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
```

It worked with all Lombok and Jackson versions for, at least, a couple of years.

Example:

```
@JsonAutoDetect(fieldVisibility = Visibility.ANY)
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_DEFAULT)
@Data
@Accessors(fluent = true)
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Person {
    String id;
    String first;
    String last;
}
```

And that's it.
Lombok and Jackson play together like a charm.

Comment: This is mutable class.

Answer (score 3):

For me it worked when I have updated lombok version to:
'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.0'

Answer (score 1):

You can get Jackson to play with just about anything if you use its ["mixin" pattern](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-docs/wiki/JacksonMixInAnnotations). Basically, it gives you a way to add Jackson annotations onto an existing class without actually modifying that class. I'm leaning towards recommending it here rather than a Lombok solution because this is solves a problem Jackson is having with a Jackson feature, so it's more likely to work long-term.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to use Gson as it does not give you all this hassle.

I added this in my spring boot app

`spring.mvc.converters.preferred-json-mapper=gson`

along with the dependency in maven and I solved all the problems. I didn't need to modify my lombok annotated pojos

Comment: Lombok team has created @Jacksonized annotation which generates all the code required from Jackson and it solved all my problems in a more clean way saving lot of time. Finally!

Answer (score 0):

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@Data
public class Person {
   String id;
   String first;
   String last;
}
```

Additional to the Data Class,  it should be correct configured the ObjectMapper. 
In this case, it is working ok with a ParameterNamesModule configuration, and setting visibility of Fields and Creator Methods

```
    om.registerModule(new ParameterNamesModule());
    om.setVisibility(FIELD, JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY);
    om.setVisibility(CREATOR, JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY);
```

Then it should work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I was having issues with getting Lombok to not add the `ConstructorProperies` annotation so went the other way and disabled Jackson from looking at that annotation.

The culprit is [JacksonAnnotationIntrospector.findCreatorAnnotation](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/blob/cf0741bed68700ecb88860a64f5e649620e6b296/src/main/java/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/introspect/JacksonAnnotationIntrospector.java#L1211). Notice:

```
if (_cfgConstructorPropertiesImpliesCreator
            && config.isEnabled(MapperFeature.INFER_CREATOR_FROM_CONSTRUCTOR_PROPERTIES)
```

Also notice [JacksonAnnotationIntrospector.setConstructorPropertiesImpliesCreator](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/blob/cf0741bed68700ecb88860a64f5e649620e6b296/src/main/java/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/introspect/JacksonAnnotationIntrospector.java#L121):

```
public JacksonAnnotationIntrospector setConstructorPropertiesImpliesCreator(boolean b)
{
    _cfgConstructorPropertiesImpliesCreator = b;
    return this;
}
```

So two options, either set the `MapperFeature.INFER_CREATOR_FROM_CONSTRUCTOR_PROPERTIES` to false or create a `JacksonAnnotationIntrospector` set `setConstructorPropertiesImpliesCreator` to `false` and set this `AnnotationIntrospector` into the `ObjectMapper` via [ObjectMapper.setAnnotationIntrospector](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html#setAnnotationIntrospector(com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.AnnotationIntrospector)).

Notice a couple things, I am using Jackson 2.8.10 and in that version `MapperFeature.INFER_CREATOR_FROM_CONSTRUCTOR_PROPERTIES` does not exist. I am not sure in which version of Jackson it was added. So if it is not there, use the `JacksonAnnotationIntrospector.setConstructorPropertiesImpliesCreator` mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have this module as well.
https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-modules-java8

then turn on -parameters flag for your compiler.

```
<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.7.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <compilerArgs>
                        <arg>-parameters</arg>
                    </compilerArgs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with this for a moment as well. But looking through the documentation [here](https://projectlombok.org/features/experimental/onX)
I can see that the onConstructor annotation parameter is considered experimental and is not supported well on my IDE (STS 4).  According to the Jackson documentation, private members are not (de)serialized by default.  There are quick ways to resolve this.

Add JsonAutoDetect annotation and set it appropriately to detect protected/private members. This is convenient for DTOs

```
@JsonAutoDetect(fieldVisibility = JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY)
public class SomeClass
```

Add a factory function with @JsonCreator annotation, this works best if you need some object validation or additional transforms.

```
public class SomeClass {

   // some code here

   @JsonCreator
   public static SomeClass factory(/* params here dressing them in @JsonProperty annotations*/) {
      return new SomeClass();
   }
}
```

Of course you could just manually add the constructor in yourself also as well.

Answer (score 0):

Options which worked for me

- This worked for me just by adding @AllArgsConstructor in my bean.
- Add  mapper.configure(MapperFeature.ACCEPT_CASE_INSENSITIVE_PROPERTIES, true); object mapper instance.

Answer (score 0):

None of the above answers worked for me, but this below did.

What happens is that Jackson does not support the fluent getters, BUT you can tell it to use reflection to read the fields.

Try this:

```
@Value
@Accessors(chain = true, fluent = true)
@Builder(builderClassName = "Builder")
public static class TestFoo {
  // ...
}

var foo = ...
var writer = new ObjectMapper()
    .setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.FIELD, JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY)
    .writer();

writer.writeValueAsString(foo);
```

Answer (score -2):

I had a different issue and it was with the boolean primitive types.

```
private boolean isAggregate;
```

It was throwing the following error as a result

```
Exception: Unrecognized field "isAggregate" (class
```

Lambok converts `isAggregate` to `isAggregate()` as a getter making the property internally to lombok as `aggregate` instead `isAggregate`. The Jackson library doesn't like it and it needs `isAggregate` property instead.

I updated the primitive boolean to Wrapper Boolean to work around this issue. There are other options for you if you are dealing with `boolean` types, see the reference below.

**Sol:**

```
private Boolean isAggregate;
```

ref: https://www.baeldung.com/lombok-getter-boolean

Comment: Did you try using aggregate instead of isAggregate with primitive type? I believe, it can resolve the error as well. Please also see this https://stackoverflow.com/a/42620096/6332074