# Lombok annotation @Getter for boolean field

Tags: java, lombok

I am using Java lombok annotation `@Getter` to generate getters for my POJO. I have a `boolean` field by the name `isAbc`.

The `@Getter` annotation in this case generates a method by the name `isAbc()`. Shouldn't it generate a method by the name `isIsAbc()`?

Comment: It's an old question, but see if this tutorial of any use: https://www.baeldung.com/lombok-getter-boolean

Answer (score 119, accepted):

Read the 'small print' section on the lombok page https://projectlombok.org/features/GetterSetter.html

> For boolean fields that start with is immediately followed by a
>   title-case letter, nothing is prefixed to generate the getter name.

So the behavior you experience is as specified.

Note that the behavior is different for `boolean` and `Boolean`:

```
@Getter
private boolean isGood; // => isGood()

@Getter
private boolean good; // => isGood()

@Getter
private Boolean isGood; // => getIsGood()
```

Comment: @serghey-bishyr you should write your own answer and not extend existing one.

Comment: @dit my answer won't be any different from existing one, just with some additional notes.

Comment: what about setters in these cases

Comment: @whishky  

For setters, "is" prefix is ignored. This means 
private boolean isGood; // => setGood()

Comment: @SergiiBishyr Thanks for improving the answer. That was definitely the right approach.

Comment: very confusing this difference between `boolean` and `Boolean`. Or is it because Boolean can be null.

Answer (score 32):

Lombok does not prefix with `is` if the name already starts with `is` followed by an uppercase letter as in `isGood`.

You might encounter names like `canDelete` which will generate a getter with the name `isCanDelete`. To avoid this you can use the `fluent` parameter:

```
@Getter(fluent = true)
private boolean canDelete;
```

or (depending on version):

```
@Getter
@Accessors(fluent = true)
private boolean canDelete;
```

In which case it will leave the name as it is so the getter becomes `canDelete()`.

Answer (score 12):

I do some tests against the lombok(1.16.8), and the conclusions are as below.

```
private Boolean good;

getter => getGood()              Boolean
setter => setGood(Boolean good)  void 


private boolean good;

getter => isGood()               boolean
setter => setGood(boolean good)  void 


private Boolean isGood;

getter => getIsGood()            Boolean
setter => setIsGood()            void 


private boolean isGood;

getter => isGood()               boolean
setter => setGood(boolean good)  void
```

Comment: How to force Lombok to generate isGood for getter on non-primitive types like `Boolean isGood` ?