# Lombok's strange choices of setter name for boolean vs Boolean fields

Tags: java, getter-setter, lombok

I observed the following strange phenomenon.  That `lombok` picks setXyz() as setter's name in only three out of the four cases; and in the fourth case, it picks setIsXyz()

```
package use_lombok;

import lombok.Data;

@Data
public class MyClass {
    boolean foo;
    Boolean bar;
    boolean isBlack;
    Boolean isRed;
    public static void main(String[] argv) {
        MyClass o1 = new MyClass();
        o1.setFoo(true);
        o1.setBar(true);
        o1.setIsRed(true);   // This is inconsistent with the others
        o1.setBlack(true);
        System.out.println(o1.toString());
    }
}
```

**Not a duplicate of a previous question**

I am aware of the discussion in another StackOverflow Q&A ([Lombok annotation @Getter for boolean field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42619986/lombok-annotation-getter-for-boolean-field)), but I am still not happy with the conclusion (that it is the way Lombok is designed).  I think Lombok should treat `boolean` and `Boolean` uniformly.

Comment: "I think Lombok should treat boolean and Boolean uniformly" Well, sorry, it doesn't.

Comment: @Michael -- Can you provide the link of the other answer?  I cited one but I don't think mine is a duplicate of the other (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42619986/lombok-annotation-getter-for-boolean-field)

Comment: "Any variation on boolean will not result in using the `is` prefix instead of the `get` prefix; for example, **returning java.lang.Boolean results in a `get` prefix, not an `is` prefix.**"

Comment: I know that statement in the small print.  The question is -- is this design justified?  Does it help programmers?

Comment: That question is opinion-based which makes it off-topic for Stack Overflow. Whether it's good or bad, that's the behaviour that they've defined. Don't like it? You can fork the project; it's [open source](https://github.com/rzwitserloot/lombok).

Comment: Well, I would accept answer/information that illustrates how that design helps programmer, or, alternatively, how it is necessary due to some other considerations.

Comment: Just saying "that is the way it is" is more opinionated than "we have to use this design because of reasons X and Y", or "because in situation W, the design actually creates less confusion"  or something like that.

Comment: Unless the lombok developers show up, all you'll get is conjecture.

Comment: Oh ... I thought you were one of the designers ... sorry :-)

Comment: The reason is Java's bean spec. It states that only `boolean`s get an `is` prefix, nothing else, not even `Boolean`s. So Lombok is designed to also treat only `boolean` special, nothing else.