# ObjectMapper Class Construction

Tags: java, json, objectmapper

I have big chunk of data, that I'd like to make it an object in java (E.g. https://haste.razvancode.com/agiyamuyol.json)

I'm running this code:

```java
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        
        File f = new File("example.json");
        if (!f.exists()) f.createNewFile();

        Board board = mapper.readValue(f, Board.class);

        System.out.println(board.getName());
```

and I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "isTemplate" (class com.razvancode.discordbot.Utils.Board$Prefs), not marked as ignorable (21 known properties: "calendarFeedEnabled", "voting", "backgroundBottomColor", "cardAging", "backgroundImage", "background", "canBePrivate", "canBeOrg", "comments", "permissionLevel", "selfJoin", "canInvite", "invitations", "backgroundTopColor", "backgroundBrightness", "hideVotes", "cardCovers", "canBeEnterprise", "backgroundTile", "canBePublic", "backgroundImageScaled"])
 at [Source: (File); line: 35, column: 23] (through reference chain: com.razvancode.discordbot.Utils.Board["prefs"]->com.razvancode.discordbot.Utils.Board$Prefs["isTemplate"])
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException.from(UnrecognizedPropertyException.java:61)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleUnknownProperty(DeserializationContext.java:823)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StdDeserializer.handleUnknownProperty(StdDeserializer.java:1153)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.handleUnknownProperty(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1589)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.handleUnknownVanilla(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1567)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:258)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.InnerClassProperty.deserializeAndSet(InnerClassProperty.java:90)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.vanillaDeserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:288)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:151)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4013)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2902)
    at com.razvancode.discordbot.Test.<init>(Test.java:28)
    at com.razvancode.discordbot.Test.main(Test.java:34)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I'm 100% sure that is from my Board class, but I'm working for hours now and I still can't get it to work.

Boardclass:

```java
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

import java.util.ArrayList;

@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Board {

    @Getter
    private Object descData, pinned, datePluginDisable, idBoardSource, limits, templateGallery, ixUpdate, idEnterprise, idMemberCreator;
    @Getter
    private String shortUrl, dateLastActivity, shortLink, creationMethod, idOrganization, dateLastView, id, url, name, desc;
    @Getter
    private boolean subscribed, starred, enterpriseOwned, closed;
    @Getter
    private ArrayList<Memberships> memberships;
    @Getter
    private ArrayList<String> idTags, powerUps, premiumFeatures;
    @Getter
    private LabelNames labelNames;
    @Getter
    private Prefs prefs;

    @NoArgsConstructor
    @AllArgsConstructor
    public static class LabelNames {

        @Getter
        private String orange, red, sky, pink, green, blue, lime, yellow, black, purple;
    }

    @NoArgsConstructor
    @AllArgsConstructor
    public static class Prefs {

        @Getter
        private String backgroundBrightness, comments, backgroundTopColor, backgroundImage, backgroundBottomColor, voting, permissionLevel, cardAging, invitations, background;
        @Getter
        private boolean canBeEnterprise, hideVotes, canBeOrg, calendarFeedEnabled, backgroundTile, canBePublic, canBePrivate, canInvite, isTemplate, cardCovers, selfJoin;
        @Getter
        private ArrayList<BackgroundImageScaled> backgroundImageScaled;
    }

    @NoArgsConstructor
    @AllArgsConstructor
    public static class BackgroundImageScaled {

        @Getter
        private String url;
        @Getter
        private Long width, height;
    }

    @NoArgsConstructor
    @AllArgsConstructor
    public static class Memberships {

        @Getter
        private String idMember, id, memberType;
        @Getter
        private boolean unconfirmed, deactivated;
    }
}
```

If you have any ideas on how can I fix it, or where I was wrong please tell me.

Comment: have a look at what Lombok is generating.

Answer (score 0):

It might be related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42619986/lombok-annotation-getter-for-boolean-field/42620096) answer. You might need to stop lombok from generating the getter as isTemplate() rather than isIsTemplate(), given that jackson will assume the boolean field in the data is called template.

Comment: It's not related to that post, The problem is on Board#Prefs#boolean values, if I set them to public it works fine, but I don't want them to be public, so if I set them to private and set Boolean instead of boolean it works again, but this gives me getIsTemplate() instead isTemplate(), and I don't think I can specify to lombok that they are boolean values not Boolean... I've tried with @Accessors(fluent = true) but then it works for the boolean values and doesn't for the Strings