# Lombok + Jackson immutables

Tags: java, spring-boot, jackson, immutability, lombok

After updating my project to Spring Boot 1.5.10
Lombok stopped working correctly with Jackson.
I mean immutable DTOs creation, when field names in my objects are not same as fields in json request:

```
@Value
@Builder
public class MyImmutableDto implements Serializable {

    @JsonProperty("other-field-1-name")
    private final BigDecimal myField1;

    @JsonProperty("other-field-2-name")
    private final String myField2;

    and a lot of fields there...
}
```

So, after updating Spring Boot to 1.5.10 this code isn't working, and I need to configure lombok like that:

```
lombok.anyConstructor.addConstructorProperties = true
```

Does anyone know any other way to create such objects with jackson + lombok without this lombok fix?
Instead of this fix I can use following code: `@JsonPOJOBuilder` and `@JsonDeserialize(builder = MyDto.MyDtoBuilder.class)`:

```
@Value
@Builder
@JsonDeserialize(builder = MyDto.MyDtoBuilder.class)
public class MyDto implements Serializable {

    // @JsonProperty("other-field-1-name")    // not working
    private final BigDecimal myField1;

    private final String myField2;
    private final String myField3;
    and a lot of fields there...

    @JsonPOJOBuilder(withPrefix = "")
    public static final class MyDtoBuilder {
    }
}
```

But it is not working with `@JsonProperty("other-field-1-name")`.
Ofc, it can be done by simple `@JsonCreator`, but maybe there is some way to use it with lombok using some constructor/jackson annotations?

Comment: I didn't get the first approach to the original problem working, so I resorted to the second and discovered that (of course) jackson annotations on fields don't carry over to builder methods, so I am interested in what comes up.

Comment: @simon posted an answer that worked for me. just want to confirm the version that you were using when you experienced this issue

Comment: You can use Lombok with immutability + Jackson:
[answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55957865/6629515)

Comment: You can use lombok builder and jackson together:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/48801237/4944734

Answer (score 2):

So this is not the exact same case, but this works for my problem. I need the @JsonDeserialize annotation on the builder, putting it there on the builder explicitly solves the problem (at the cost of boilerplate code). At least I don't need to type out the rest of the builder.

```java
@Value
@Builder
@JsonDeserialize(builder = ProductPrice.ProductPriceBuilder.class)
public class ProductPrice {

    @JsonSerialize(using = MoneySerializer.class)
    @JsonDeserialize(using = MoneyDeserializer.class)
    Money price;

    Duration rentalLength;

    Period recurrence;

    @JsonPOJOBuilder(withPrefix = "")
    public static class ProductPriceBuilder{
        @JsonDeserialize(using = MoneyDeserializer.class)
        public ProductPrice.ProductPriceBuilder price(Money price) {
            this.price = price;
            return this;
        }  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering that this question was asked after Jan 2017, I'm assuming that you may have upgraded your version of Lombok `1.16.20`along with Spring Boot. And still using JDK 8

You can update your version of Spring Boot, but may want to keep your Lombok version at `1.16.18`. This will let you implement your extra customization and deserialization via builder work around. That is, as long as you haven't made use of any new lombok annotations.

There was a good amount of effort in 1.16.20 specifically that addresses breaking changes in JDK 9 which can potentially cause issues moving forward on JDK 8.

[1.16.20 @Data object no longer constructable for jackson?](https://github.com/rzwitserloot/lombok/issues/1563) < Other individuals who recognized similar issues.