# Deserialize ImmutableList using Jackson & Lombok

Tags: java, java-8, jackson, deserialization, lombok

I am trying to get the following example working:

```
    @Value
    @JsonDeserialize(builder = SomeClass.Builder.class)
    @Builder(builderClassName = "Builder")
    public static class SomeClass {
        @Wither
        ImmutableList<String> words;

        @JsonPOJOBuilder(withPrefix = "")
        public static class Builder {
        }
    }

    @Test
    @SneakyThrows
    public void serializeTest() {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        SomeClass someClass = SomeClass.builder()
            .words(ImmutableList.of("word1", "word2", "word3"))
            .build();
        String jsonString = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(someClass);
        log.info("serialized: {}", jsonString);
        SomeClass newSomeClass = objectMapper.readValue(jsonString, SomeClass.class);
        log.info("done");
        newSomeClass.words.forEach(w -> log.info("word {}", w));
    }
```

however it fails with

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot find a deserializer for non-concrete Collection type [collection type; class com.google.common.collect.ImmutableList, contains [simple type, class java.lang.String]]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BasicDeserializerFactory.createCollectionDeserializer(BasicDeserializerFactory.java:1205)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createDeserializer2(DeserializerCache.java:399)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createDeserializer(DeserializerCache.java:349)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createAndCache2(DeserializerCache.java:264)
```

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48644809/lombok-jackson-immutables), I attempted something like:

```
    @Value
    @JsonDeserialize(builder = SomeClass.Builder.class)
    @Builder(builderClassName = "Builder")
    public static class SomeClass {
        @Wither
        @JsonDeserialize(using = ImmutableListDeserializer.class)
        ImmutableList<String> words;

        @JsonPOJOBuilder(withPrefix = "")
        public static class Builder {
        }
    }

    @Test
    @SneakyThrows
    public void serializeTest() {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        SomeClass someClass = SomeClass.builder()
            .words(ImmutableList.of("word1", "word2", "word3"))
            .build();
        String jsonString = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(someClass);
        log.info("serialized: {}", jsonString);
        SomeClass newSomeClass = objectMapper.readValue(jsonString, SomeClass.class);
        log.info("done");
        newSomeClass.words.forEach(w -> log.info("word {}", w));
    }
```

but that fails with:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot find a deserializer for non-concrete Collection type [collection type; class com.google.common.collect.ImmutableList, contains [simple type, class java.lang.String]]
```

Due to the constraints of the project I'm working on, I cannot modify the object mapper.
So I cannot simply do:

```
objectMapper.registerModule(new GuavaModule());
```

which would have worked.

Is there any other straightforward way to get a simple ImmutableList deserialization working?

**Edit:** I managed to get a different error with below:

```
    @Value
    @JsonDeserialize(builder = SomeClass.Builder.class)
    @Builder(builderClassName = "Builder")
    public static class SomeClass {
        @Wither
        ImmutableList<String> strings;

        @JsonPOJOBuilder(withPrefix = "")
        public static class Builder {
            @JsonDeserialize(using = ImmutableListDeserializer.class)
            public Builder strings(ImmutableList<String> strings) {
                this.strings = strings;
                return this;
            }
        }
    }

    @Test
    @SneakyThrows
    public void serializeTest() {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        SomeClass someClass = SomeClass.builder()
            .strings(ImmutableList.of("word1", "word2", "word3"))
            .build();
        String jsonString = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(someClass);
        log.info("serialized: {}", jsonString);
        SomeClass newSomeClass = objectMapper.readValue(jsonString, SomeClass.class);
        log.info("done");
        newSomeClass.strings.forEach(w -> log.info("word {}", w));
    }
```

which throws:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Class com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.guava.deser.ImmutableListDeserializer has no default (no arg) constructor
```

maybe that is easier to solve if I could build a no arg constructor for ImmutableListDeserializer, or something like that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to write a custom serializer in the end. If you have a more elegant answer please let me know. Here is a working example for whoever might end up here:

```
    @Value
    @JsonDeserialize(builder = SomeClass.Builder.class)
    @Builder(builderClassName = "Builder")
    public static class SomeClass {
        @Wither
        ImmutableList<String> strings;

        @JsonPOJOBuilder(withPrefix = "")
        public static class Builder {
            @JsonDeserialize(using = CustomDeserializer.class)
            public Builder strings(ImmutableList<String> strings) {
                this.strings = strings;
                return this;
            }
        }
    }

    public static class CustomDeserializer extends StdDeserializer<ImmutableList<String>> {
        public CustomDeserializer() {
            super(ImmutableList.class);
        }

        @Override
        public ImmutableList<String> deserialize(JsonParser parser, DeserializationContext deserializer) throws IOException {
            ImmutableList.Builder<String> immutableListBuilder = ImmutableList.builder();
            while (!parser.isClosed()) {
                JsonToken jsonToken = parser.nextToken();
                if (JsonToken.VALUE_STRING.equals(jsonToken)) {
                    final String fieldValue = parser.getValueAsString();
                    immutableListBuilder.add(fieldValue);
                } else if (JsonToken.END_ARRAY.equals(jsonToken)) {
                    break;
                }
            }
            return immutableListBuilder.build();
        }
    }

    @Test
    @SneakyThrows
    public void serializeTest() {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        SomeClass someClass = SomeClass.builder()
            .strings(ImmutableList.of("word1", "word2", "word3"))
            .build();
        String jsonString = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(someClass);
        log.info("serialized: {}", jsonString);
        SomeClass newSomeClass = objectMapper.readValue(jsonString, SomeClass.class);
        log.info("done");
        newSomeClass.strings.forEach(w -> log.info("word {}", w));
    }
```

a really nice article I found about this: http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-json/jackson-objectmapper.html

Comment: Please check my solution below.

Answer (score 1):

1. Have the IDE generate the constructor
2. Add `@JsonCreator` to the constructor
3. Add the `ParameterNamesModule`
4. Add the`GuavaModule` to the mapper.
5. Compile with the `-parameters` flag

```java
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonCreator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.guava.GuavaModule;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jdk8.Jdk8Module;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.paramnames.ParameterNamesModule;
import com.google.common.collect.ImmutableList;

import lombok.AccessLevel;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Singular;
import lombok.Value;
import lombok.With;
import lombok.extern.log4j.Log4j2;

@SuppressWarnings("javadoc")
@Log4j2
public class Q61900327 {

    /**
     * We add the ParameterNamesModule so Jackson can use the constructor arguments to
     * properly map the fields.
     */
    static final ObjectMapper OBJECT_MAPPER = new ObjectMapper().registerModule(new GuavaModule())
            .registerModule(new ParameterNamesModule())
            .registerModule(new Jdk8Module());

    /**
     * This solution works at the cost of having the IDE generate the constructor.
     */
    static class ExplicitConstructorSolution {

        @Value
        @Builder(toBuilder = true)
        public static class SomeClass {

            @With
            @Singular
            private ImmutableList<String> words;

            @JsonCreator
            public SomeClass(ImmutableList<String> words) {
                super();
                this.words = words;
            }
        }

        @Test
        void serializeTest() throws JsonProcessingException {


            var someClass = SomeClass.builder()
                    .word("word1")
                    .word("word2")
                    .word("word3")
                    .build();

            try {
                var jsonString = OBJECT_MAPPER.writeValueAsString(someClass);
                log.info("serialized: {}", jsonString);
                var newSomeClass = OBJECT_MAPPER.readValue(jsonString, SomeClass.class);
                newSomeClass.words.forEach(w -> log.info("word {}", w));
            }
            catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
                log.error("someClass could not roundtrip.", e);
                throw e;
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Note this solution looks great but unfortunately will cause javadoc to fail with:
     * <p>
     * {@code
     * error: cannot find symbol  [ERROR] @AllArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PUBLIC, onConstructor_ =
     * { @JsonCreator })}
     * <p>
     * @see <a href="https://github.com/rzwitserloot/lombok/issues/2137">lombok #2137</a>
     *
     */
    static class OnConstructorSolution {

        @Value
        @AllArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PUBLIC, onConstructor_ = { @JsonCreator })
        @Builder(toBuilder = true)
        public static class SomeClass {

            @With
            @Singular
            private ImmutableList<String> words;
        }

        @Test
        void serializeTest() throws JsonProcessingException {

            var someClass = SomeClass.builder()
                    .word("word1")
                    .word("word2")
                    .word("word3")
                    .build();

            try {
                var jsonString = OBJECT_MAPPER.writeValueAsString(someClass);
                log.info("serialized: {}", jsonString);
                var newSomeClass = OBJECT_MAPPER.readValue(jsonString, SomeClass.class);
                newSomeClass.words.forEach(w -> log.info("word {}", w));
            }
            catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
                log.error("someClass could not roundtrip.", e);
                throw e;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

pom:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>io.jeffmaxwell.stackoverflow</groupId>
  <artifactId>stackoverflow</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>

    <maven-compiler-plugin.version>3.8.1</maven-compiler-plugin.version>
    <maven.compiler.source>14</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>14</maven.compiler.target>
    <maven.compiler.release>14</maven.compiler.release>
    <maven.compiler.parameters>true</maven.compiler.parameters>
    <maven.compiler.showDeprecation>true</maven.compiler.showDeprecation>
    <maven.compiler.showWarnings>true</maven.compiler.showWarnings>
    <maven.compiler.verbose>true</maven.compiler.verbose>

    <maven-dependency-plugin.version>3.1.2</maven-dependency-plugin.version>

    <guava.version>29.0-jre</guava.version>
    <junit.version>5.6.2</junit.version>
    <log4j2.version>2.13.3</log4j2.version>
    <jackson.version>2.11.0</jackson.version>
    <lombok.version>1.18.12</lombok.version>
  </properties>

  <build>
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>${maven-compiler-plugin.version}</version>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>${maven-dependency-plugin.version}</version>
          <configuration>
            <outputXML>true</outputXML>
            <verbose>true</verbose>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>

  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>${guava.version}</version>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-bom</artifactId>
        <version>${junit.version}</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-bom</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-bom</artifactId>
        <version>${log4j2.version}</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <version>${lombok.version}</version>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
      <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
      <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-datatype-guava</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jdk8</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-module-parameter-names</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j-1.2-api</artifactId>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j-jcl</artifactId>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: Hi, first of all thanks a lot for putting effort on this! And especially for sharing a full example with pom included. There is one problem I also noted in the question though: I can't use "objectMapper.registerModule(new GuavaModule());", because the example I posted is a simplified version of a bigger project, and one of the dependencies is using their own objectMapper to map an input object that I am not able to modify :/

Comment: Is that objectmapper configured in spring boot by any chance?

Comment: Also do you have the ability to add dependencies?

Comment: Unfortunately no for both :/ we use Guice for dependency injection. It is a large project, and it is not easy to do arbitrary changes on dependencies.