# Jackson + FAIL_ON_MISSING_CREATOR_PROPERTIES + Lombok

Tags: jackson, deserialization, lombok

I'm attempting to use a Jackson flag on the objectMapper

```
objectMapper.enable(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_MISSING_CREATOR_PROPERTIES);
```

This should cause object deserialization to fail if a constructor argument is not set in the json. i.e. If a field is missing as opposed to being set to null.

But I noticed that it only works if the object I want to deserialize has a constructor like so

```
public MyObject(@JsonProperty("id") UUID id, @JsonProperty("url") URL url) {
    this.id = id;
    this.url = url;
}
```

That's a little problematic as I'd hoped to use lombok's @AllArgsConstructor to generate the constructor. But if the constructor is missing the @JsonProperty(..) the FAIL_ON_MISSING_CREATOR_PROPERTIES check does not work. Instead the parameters are passed in as null.

I've come across some solutions here [Can't make Jackson and Lombok work together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39381474/cant-make-jackson-and-lombok-work-together). But so far they're not working for me.

Any suggestions?

--- Update ---

The annotations on my class are

```
@Data
@Builder
@ToString
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode
@JsonAutoDetect(fieldVisibility = JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY)
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_DEFAULT)
public class MyClass { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

The following combination of annotations work fine with Lombok 1.18.0 and Jackson 2.9 (the most recent versions as of July 2018):

```java
@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public static class Foo {
    private UUID id;
    private String url;
}
```

```java
String json = "{\n" +
              "  \"id\": \"32783be3-5355-41d2-807b-619e3481d220\",\n" +
              "  \"url\": \"http://example.com\"\n" +
              "}";

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Foo foo = mapper.readValue(json, Foo.class);
```

Comment: I am using the no args constructor. Updated my answer with the annotations on the class.