# Lombok + Jackson => MismatchedInputException

Tags: java, jackson, lombok

I have a `PSQL` table with one column containing `jsonb` data:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS user (
    user_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    user_email VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    user_address jsonb NOT NULL
)
```

I have the following `java object` for that:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonDeserialize;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonPOJOBuilder;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Value;

@Value
@Builder
public class User {
    private String userName;
    private String userEmail;
    private UserAddress address;

    @Value
    @Builder
    @JsonDeserialize(builder = UserAddress.UserAddressBuilder.class)
    public static class UserAddress {
        @JsonProperty("street")
        private String street;
        @JsonProperty("house_number")
        private String houseNumber;

        @JsonPOJOBuilder(withPrefix = "")
        public static class UserAddressBuilder {
            private String street = null;
            private String houseNumber = null;

            public UserAddressBuilder street(String street) {
               this.street = street;

               return this;
            }

            public UserAddressBuilder houseNumber(String houseNumber) {
                this.houseNumber = houseNumber;

                return this;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I now build the `User` from a `ResultSet`:

```
return User.builder()
        .userName(rs.getString(SqlConstants.TableUser.USER_NAME))
        .userEmail(rs.getString(SqlConstants.TableUser.USER_EMAIL))
        .userAddress(mapper.convertValue(rs.getString(SqlConstants.TableUser.USER_ADDRESS), User.UserAddress.class))
        .build();
```

I always get the exception:

> Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot construct instance of `my.package.model.User$UserAddress$UserAddressBuilder` (although at least one Creator exists): no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('"{\"street\":\"Some Street\",\"house_number\":\"Some House Number\"}')

I cannot find the source of this problem since the fields are matching, arent they?
I also tried the approach without `@Builder` and used `@Data`, `@AllArgsConstructor` and `@NoArgsConstructor` instead.

I get the same result when using `readValue` instead of `convertValue`

Comment: The error is very explicit, you are supposed to have a constructor that takes the string to deserialize as parameter in your builder class.

Comment: I dont think that I understand what you mean. I took the answer from here and implemented it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39381474/cant-make-jackson-and-lombok-work-together

Comment: You should use `mapper.readValue()`, not `convertValue()`.

Comment: I tried it already. Same result.

Comment: Your UserAddressBuilder class has no constructor?

Comment: Updated post with builder functions. Builder needs no constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in comments using

```
.userAddress(mapper.readValue(rs.getString(SqlConstants.TableUser.USER_ADDRESS), 
                                              User.UserAddress.class))
```

should work just fine at least it does for me. However after that change you might run into:

> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "house_number" ...

(instead of the original error) which will be fixed by small change to your `UserAddressBuilder`:

```
@JsonProperty("house_number") // this is also needed to map correctly
public UserAddressBuilder houseNumber(String houseNumber) { ...
```

From [Javadoc](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.0.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html#convertValue(java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Class)):

> public  T convertValue(Object fromValue, Class toValueType)
>                  throws IllegalArgumentException
>
> Convenience method for doing two-step conversion from given value, into instance of given value type. **This is functionality equivalent to first serializing given value into JSON, then binding JSON data into value of given type**, but may be executed without fully serializing into JSON. Same converters (serializers, deserializers) will be used as for data binding, meaning same object mapper configuration works

while `readValue` is for reading from string, stream, reader into a object value. With `convertValue(..)` you might need converters defined but in your case it is not needed.

Comment: I dont get why but this solved the issue. I do not understand the `MismatchedInputException` .