# Getting around Json jackson and lombok constructor requirements

Tags: java, json, jackson, annotations, lombok

Using json to save and load data requires a constructor for json to load the object, and I'm having trouble getting lombok annotations to work with this. What should I do?

This is what my class looked like before and after attempting to use an annotation to construct my item:

```
@Data
public class Item { //before

    private int id;

    private int amount;

    public Item(@JsonProperty("id") int id, @JsonProperty("amount") int amount) {
        this.id = id;
        this.amount = amount;
    }

}
```

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor 
@NoArgsConstructor //I don't want this here as it could cause complications in other places.  But json requires I have this...
public class Item { //after

    private int id;

    private int amount;

}
```

I don't want to use the NoArgsConstructor annotation by lombok as I don't want a no args constructor for this class. I realise that I could do this:

```
private Item() {
}
```

But was hoping there is a better way...

Comment: try to use `@AllArgsConstructor(suppressConstructorProperties = true)`

Comment: @YCF_L that method is deprecated

Comment: Try `@AllArgsConstructor(onConstructor = @__(@JsonCreator))`, see also [Can't deserialize simplest Object with final field bu Jackson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55323307/cant-deserialize-simplest-object-with-final-field-bu-jackson)

Answer (score 4):

Since lombok 1.18.4, you can configure what annotations are copied to the constructor parameters. Insert this into your `lombok.config`:

```
lombok.copyableAnnotations += com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty
```

Then just add `@JsonProperty` to your fields:

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor 
public class Item {
    @JsonProperty("id")
    private int id;

    @JsonProperty("amount")
    private int amount;
}
```

Although the annotation parameters may seem unnecessary, they are in fact required, because at runtime the names of the constructor parameters are not available.

Comment: Fantastic, allows you to use `final` fields as well

Answer (score 2):

try adding this to your lombok config file:

```
lombok.anyConstructor.addConstructorProperties=true
config.stopBubbling = true
```

Comment: Is there no better way than this? Is there no way to annotate the constructor arguments with @JsonProprty as done in the first example of code by adding them to the AllArgsConstructor in example 2? I.e @AllArgsConstructor(argumentsAnnotation = @JsonProperty)

Answer (score 0):

So what you're saying is that Jackson requires no-args constructor for deserialization, and you don't want to add no-args constructors to your classes because that doesn't play well with your model.

Lombok is completely irrelevant here - it makes zero difference whether no-args constructor would be written manually or generated by Lombok, it'll still be just a no-args constructor.

Your real question is - can I make Jackson work without no-argument constructors on target classes. There are multiple answers to that already, you have almost done it. Here's what has to be done:

1. Add `@JsonCreator` annotation to your constructor
2. Add `@JsonProperty("propName")` to constructor parameters

You did the #2 but not #1. Add that and this should fix your problem.

Comment: And how to make something like `@Data` (Lombok) generate `@JsonCreator` onto its required-args constructor?

Comment: Can't do it with Lombok unfortunately - if you want custom annotations you have to add the constructor with these annotations manually.

Comment: I actually found out, that there is somewhat of a way - see https://projectlombok.org/features/experimental/onX. One can write something like this `@AllArgsConstructor(onConstructor=@__(@Inject))`, which would supposedly annotate the all-args constructor with a `@Inject` annotation (this is just an example). It's ugly, but I believe this is what I ended up using: `@Data @RequiredArgsConstructor (onConstructor_ = {@ConstructorProperties ( {"property1", "property2"})})`, annotated at the actual class. Perhaps at this point writing the constructor manually might be a better idea, though.