# Can't deserialize simplest Object with final field bu Jackson

Tags: java, jackson

I just want to serialize and deserialize simple immutable object and don't understand why I can't do it using Jackson

```
import java.io.IOException;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import lombok.Value;

public class TestApplication {

    @Value
    static class Test {
        private final String a;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

        String res = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(new Test("test"));
        System.out.println(res);

        System.out.println(objectMapper.readValue(res, Test.class));
    }
}
```

It fails with exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot construct instance of `com.devchallange.rogatakopita.RogatakopitaApplication$Test` (although at least one Creator exists): cannot deserialize from Object value (no delegate- or property-based Creator)
 at [Source: (String)"{"a":"test"}"; line: 1, column: 2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException.from(MismatchedInputException.java:63)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.reportInputMismatch(DeserializationContext.java:1343)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleMissingInstantiator(DeserializationContext.java:1032)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.deserializeFromObjectUsingNonDefault(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1297)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserializeFromObject(BeanDeserializer.java:326)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:159)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4013)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3004)
    at com.devchallange.rogatakopita.RogatakopitaApplication.main(RogatakopitaApplication.java:29)
```

I understand that answer should be easy but it's like the most common case that should work from the box isn't it?

Comment: [The code provided does not compile](https://ideone.com/zRRtYd). Thus, it is impossible that the code provided does produce the exception provided.

Answer (score 2):

When designing immutable classes, Jackson should invoke the constructor with all the required arguments.

If you were not using lombok,

- Annotate the constructor you want Jackson to invoke with `@JsonCreator`.
- Annotate the constructor parameters with `@JsonProperty`. If you want to skip this, you can add use `ParameterNamesModule` extension.

Example:

```
static class Test {

    private final String a;

    public Test() {
        a = "default";
    }

    @JsonCreator // Jackson will use this constructor during deserialization
    public Test(@JsonProperty("a") String a) { // @JsonProperty can be skipped if you use ParameterNamesModule annotation
        this.a = a;
    }

    // Getter for A
}
```

Lombok's `@Value` annotation produces only a single all-args constructor which we need to annotate with `@JsonCreator`. This can be done by annotating the class with `@AllArgsConstructor(onConstructor = @__(@JsonCreator))`.

Since the constructor is auto-generated, we will not be able to annotate the parameters with `@JsonProperty`, so, you'll have to use `ParameterNamesModule`.

Code snippet with these changes:

```
public class TestApplication {

    @Value
    @AllArgsConstructor(onConstructor = @__(@JsonCreator))
    static final class Test {
        private final String a;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        objectMapper.registerModule(new ParameterNamesModule());

        String res = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(new Test("test"));
        System.out.println(res);
        System.out.println(objectMapper.readValue(res, Test.class));
    }
}
```

Following is the maven dependency for parameter names module.

```
 <dependency>
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-module-parameter-names</artifactId>
      <version>2.9.8</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
 </dependency>
```

Answer (score -1):

In java a final attribute must be set in the constructor and can only be read later.
But jackson tries to change that attribute later on. So you cannot use jackson to fill a final field.