# Deserialize embedded JSON-String as typed Object

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, jackson, json-deserialization

Given these to models (using Lombok @Data for simplicity)

```
@Data
public class RootModel {
    private Integer myRootProperty;
    private SubModel mySubModel;
}

@Data
public class SubModel {
    private Integer mySubProperty
}
```

and this JSON-String:

```
{
    "myRootProperty" : 5,
    "mySubModel" : "{ "mySubProperty" : 3 }"
}
```

Is it possible (via Jackson-Annotations) to directly deserialze the embedded JSON-String (which origins from a DB-Column) to its Java-POJO-Model?

Background is that we need a JSON-Formatted configuration in our DB and I want to handle it typesafe as soon as possible - ideally directly after deserialization.

Comment: Without those quotes being escaped that's not valid JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it sure is. Just annotate with the `@JsonProperty` tag

```
@Data
public class RootModel {
    @JsonProperty("myRootProperty")
    private Integer myRootProperty;

    @JsonProperty("mySubModel")
    private SubModel mySubModel;
}

@Data
public class SubModel {
    @JsonProperty("mySubProperty")
    private Integer mySubProperty
}
```

Then use the object mapper to deserialise into the POJO

```
RootModel rootModel = objectMapper.readValue(jsonString, RootModel.class);
```

Comment: If I do this, I get an Exception: 

Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot construct instance of `SubModel` (although at least one Creator exists): no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('{"mySubProperty": 3}')

Please note that the JSON is Embedded as String into the Input-Json - I guess I need something like a "Json-String-Constructor" (or alike) in SubModel...

Comment: oh right, this is a Jackson vs Lombok thing, where Lombok is creating a constructor that is affecting how Jackson uses default constructors. check out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39381474/cant-make-jackson-and-lombok-work-together, there's probably a few of these strategies that will work

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies with your `Json` string. If you take a look at your `Json`,

```
{
    "myRootProperty" : 5,
    "mySubModel" : "{ "mySubProperty" : 3 }"
}
```

The subnode is enclosed in `""` like `"{ "mySubProperty" : 3 }"` which will be considered as it is a `value`. 
Instead if your `Json` is like as specified below (Note:I only removed the double quotes) like `{ "mySubProperty" : 3 }`, deserialization won't complain any more. Your typical Json string would look like specified below.

```
{
    "myRootProperty" : 5,
    "mySubModel" : { "mySubProperty" : 3 }
}
```

Comment: This is actually part of the problem - a string value containing a JSON structure.

Comment: You can't change the JSON? I don't follow

Answer (score 0):

No there is no automated way to do that. You could try a custom deserializer. Otherwise read it as just string and convert that to Typed Object in another step.

Comment: The latter is my current solution - it works this way but I hoped I could avoid this additional step.