# java.lang.Long is not a functional interface

Tags: java, generics, consumer, functional-interface, supplier

I created this GenericBuilder class (barely inspired by [How to implement the builder pattern in Java 8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31754786/how-to-implement-the-builder-pattern-in-java-8))

```
public class GenericBuilder<T> {

    private final T instance;

    private GenericBuilder(T instance) {
        this.instance = instance;
    }

    public static <T> GenericBuilder<T> of(Supplier<T> instantiator) {
        return new GenericBuilder<T>(instantiator.get());
    }

    public <U> GenericBuilder<T> with(BiConsumer<T, U> consumer,
                                      U value) {
        ((Consumer<T>) t -> consumer.accept(t, value)).accept(instance);
        return this;
    }

    public <U> GenericBuilder<T> with(BiConsumer<T, U> consumer,
                                      Supplier<U> supplier) {
        return with(consumer, supplier.get());
    }

    public T build() {
        return instance;
    }
}
```

But the second with() method throws

> incompatible types: cannot infer type-variable(s) U
>   (argument mismatch; java.lang.Long is not a functional interface)

when I execute the following:

```
GenericBuilder.of(Dto::new)
        .with(Dto::setId, entity::getId)
        .build();
```

Notice that **entity** is an instance of an **Entity** class.

Comment: could you provide some sample data to reproduce the said error with?

Comment: I may just be missing something, but why can't `with` be implemented as just `consumer.accept(instance, value)`? Why declare a separate lambda if you're just going to immediately invoke it?

Comment: What version of Java are you compiling with?

Comment: Daniel, you are right, thanks for advice but the error remains.
Jacob, java version "1.8.0_152".

Comment: Can you try updating to a later version of Java (preferably 11) and tell us if the error persists? There have been many inference improvements in later versions.

Comment: With type erasure I imagine overloading ```with()``` is problematic. Have you tried with just the ```with(BiConsumer, Supplier)``` variant present?