# Constructor showing 'found no arguments' when arguments provided

Tags: java, arguments

new member, first time poster. Please forgive any mistakes or faux pas in my question.

Superclass:

```
public Person(String n,String pos, String db, String dW, TimePeriods tP,double bS,IManager m){
    setName(n);
    position=Position.valueOf(pos);
    dob=LocalDate.parse(db);
    dateWorking=LocalDate.parse(dW);
    timePeriod=tP;
    baseSalary=bS;
}
```

Subclass:

```
private CEO(String n,String pos, String dob, String dW, TimePeriods tP,double bS, IManager m){
}
```

My error, happening on the subclass CEO constructor:

> constructor Person in class Person cannot be applied to given types; 
>   required: String,String,String,String,TimePeriods,double,IManager
>   found: no arguments   reason: actual and formal argument lists differ
>   in length

Can anyone help me find out why it isn't finding my arguments?

Comment: I don't see an explicit call to `super()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you didn't call the `Person` constructor (using `super(..)`) inside `CEO` class constructor, the compiler tries to add the default `super()` in the first line of `CEO` constructor.

But, the call default `super()` fails to compile as you don't have a **zero-parameters constructor** for `Person` class.

So, add the `super(n, pos, dob, etc..)` call in your `CEO` class as shown below:

```
public CEO(String n,String pos, String dob, 
        String dW, TimePeriods tP,double bS, IManager m){
  super(n, pos, dob, dw, tP, bS, m);//calls superclass i.e., Person constructor
}
```

Also, you have got **huge argument list for the constructors** of your classes, which is very hard to read/maintain, I strongly suggest you need to consider refactoring your classes using **Builder pattern** (look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/328496/when-would-you-use-the-builder-pattern)) so that it reduces the complexity and the code can be easy to read and maintain.

Comment: Fast and beautiful! Thanks so much for your help.
I'm definitely going to look into Builder Pattern, but my current project structure has been dictated by the textbook and I'm not at liberty to change it.
Thanks again!