# What does `.build()` do in the context of Google Analytics for Android?

Tags: java, android, google-analytics

This code initializes a new EventBuilder object and sets values on the object. Why is .build() necessary at the end?

```
tracker.send(new HitBuilders.EventBuilder()
    .setCategory("Achievement")
    .setAction("Unlocked")
    .setLabel("5 Dragons Rescued")
    .setValue(1)
    .build());
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When would you use the Builder Pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/328496/when-would-you-use-the-builder-pattern)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are creating an instance of a `HitBuilders.EventBuilder`. Usually — particularly in Android-related development — when you see a class end in `...Builder`, it employs [the builder pattern](http://howtodoinjava.com/design-patterns/creational/builder-pattern-in-java/). And, when the `...Builder` class is a `static` class inside something else, the builder builds an instance of the outer class. In this case, presumably `HitBuilders.EventBuilder` creates an instance of `HitBuilders`.

`build()` is the convention for a builder class to create the requested instance.