# Convert Java pojo to json String

Tags: java, json, objectmapper

I have the following java class

```
public  class TabularDescriptor extends ReportDescriptor {

    private String generatorClass;
    private String targetClass;
    private String name;
    private String sublabel;
    private String reportName;
    private List<MappingMetadata> mappings = null;
    private List<TabularColumnGroup> columnGroups = null;
    private List<TabularStates> states = null;
:
:
     and its getters and settere
```

I have entity classes for  each of those List like MappingMetadata,TabularColumnGroup,TabularStates.
I want to get a json data for this pojo classes. What can I do for it.

And what is the use of

```
    public JSONObject toJSON() {
        JSONObject ret = new JSONObject();
        ret.put("generatorClass", this.generatorClass);
        ret.put("targetClass", this.targetClass);
        ret.put("name", this.name);
        :
        :
        return ret;
    }
```

And is there anyway I can display my json content on browser if yes how can I? Thanks.

Comment: Have a look at https://github.com/google/gson. It seems to be exactly what you're looking for. You can easily serialize and deserialize Java Objects using it.

Answer (score 12):

There are 2 libraries that deal with JSON serialization/deserialization using Java:

1. ### [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson)

   The go-to library for Java serialization/deserialization([docs](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-docs)). A default choice for the JSON interaction within Java for the majority of developers. Comes completely embedded with all dependencies in `spring-boot-starter-web` and `spring-boot-starter-webflux`, dependency starters of [Spring Boot](https://spring.io/projects/spring-boot) - popular Java IOC/DI framework.

   #### Dependencies <sub>(databind is the main dependency, for annotations and additional features you will need more Jackson dependencies)</sub>:

   *Maven:*

   ```xml
   <dependency>
       <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
       <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
       <version>${jackson.version}</version>   
   </dependency>
   ```

   *Gradle:*

   ```
   dependencies {
      implementation "com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:${yourVersion}"
   }
   ```

   #### Serialization Snippet:

   ```java
   TabularDescriptor tabularDescriptor = new TabularDescriptor();
   ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
   String json = mapper.writeValueAsString(tabularDescriptor);
   ```
2. ### [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson)

   Google's library for a Java serialization/deserialization([docs](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/latest/com.google.gson/module-summary.html)).

   #### Dependencies:

   *Gradle:*

   ```
   dependencies { 
       implementation "com.google.code.gson:gson:${yourVersion}"
   }
   ```

   *Maven:*

   ```xml
   <dependency>
       <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
       <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
       <version>${gson.version}</version>
   </dependency>
   ```

   #### Serialization Snippet:

   ```java
   TabularDescriptor tabularDescriptor = new TabularDescriptor();
   Gson gson = new Gson();
   String json = gson.toJson(obj);
   ```

**Details worth noting**: You have to have all getters/setters public for both complete serialization and complete deserialization of an object(in its simplest form). An empty constructor is a must in any case.

**Reference Information**:

1. [JSON in Java by Baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/java-json)
2. [Jackson vs Gson by Baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-vs-gson)

Answer (score 6):

I would recommend you to add Jackson to your project, it's rather easy to use.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.8</version>
</dependency>
```

And in Java Code can be used as so:

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
String json = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(tabularDescriptor);
TabularDescriptor newTabularDescriptor = objectMapper.readValue(json, TabularDescriptor.class);
```

Comment: Thank you. What is value in tabularDescriptor. Is it the value I set using its setter? If yes how can I set  value to pojo classes like MappingMetadata.

Comment: @Lilac 1) `tabularDescriptor` is your object e.g. `TabularDescriptor tabularDescriptor = new TabularDescriptor(...);` 2) Not sure that I get what you mean here. Are you refering to how to create objects? Easiest way is to use a [Builder Pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1953567/8794926), especially in your case since you have a lot of inner objects in the tabular descriptor.

Comment: Thank you. I wasn't sure how to give values for the inner objects.

Answer (score 4):

You can use **ObjectMapper** or **Gson** for Class to JSON conversion and vice-versa.

(I would recommend ObjectMapper)

> - Object Mapper
>
> [Intro to the Jackson ObjectMapper](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-object-mapper-tutorial)
>
> - GSON
>
> [How to convert Java object to / from JSON](https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-do-convert-java-object-to-from-json-format-gson-api/)
>
> - Comparison
>
> [Jackson(ObjectMapper) vs Gson](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-vs-gson)